# Cancelling upvote on comment?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, up-votes, comment-voting

As mentioned on [uservoice](http://web.archive.org/web/20130502064817/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/forums/1722-general/suggestions/164247-you-can-t-undo-comment-votes-):

> For something that can be done so
>   easily by accident, there should be
>   the ability to undo mistakes.

I know that I have clicked several times on a comment up-vote without actually wanting to.

I would suggest being able to cancel the up-vote (maybe only for a couple of minutes or even less than a minute, no problem, as long as I can undo a miss-click).

Comment: Does an upvote more or less really matter on a comment? I upvoted Mosty although I don't agree... :)

Comment: @TomWijsman It kind of matters when you're arguing a case and accidentally upvote the guy who's wrong :/

Comment: @Dunhamzzz: Comments aren't meant for discussion though, but rather as a reflection of the post.

Comment: 30-60 seconds timer would be nice. Just to be able to revert misclicks on **really dumb** comments (like the one i upvoted few minutes ago).

Comment: I totally just upvoted a guy's comment right after I finished completely disagreeing with him in my comment. It's kind of an important missing feature that I can't undo that mis-click.

Comment: I don't see why this would be so hard to implement, delay sending of a comment vote via AJAX for 2-5 seconds so that the user has time to quickly click again to remove the vote. If they're too slow, it sticks, which isn't a big deal, as we're already dealing with it.

Comment: I would love to see this implemented. I just went to get a perma-link to a comment, and clicked the arrow since thats what I'm used to doing in chat to get a perma-link to a chat message. It would be great if I have a small window of time to undo the upvote before it becomes permanent

Comment: I'm just going to let this bounty expire as a sign of protest if no official answer is given for why this is declined :)

Comment: I just did this on a comment about 5 minutes ago and would love to have had the opportunity to clear the upvote since the comment I upvoted was clearly wrong.

Comment: I up-voted a fresh comment that was subsequently edited by the user into something with the opposite meaning.  My initial vote was not an accident but now through no fault of mine, it's no longer applicable to this comment.  Since the actual _content_ of the comment was changed, there *should* be *no* restriction on removing my vote, time limit or other.

Comment: Eight years later, I still want to know the *motivation* for locking comment upvotes, when votes on answers are not locked.

Comment: How about if I upvoted a comment then came to a better understanding a few minutes later?  In such a situation, bad data has been entered by the user, the user has come to a better understanding within a few minutes that their upvote was a mistake, the user comes back to fix the bad data entered but is prevented from doing so.  This is such a legitimate use case, and it just happened to me.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

I just added this, but there are some ground rules:

1. You can un-upvote a comment within the first 60 seconds, provided you did not navigate away.
2. Once you un-upvote a comment you can not upvote it again.

We do not want flip flopping, nor do we want people to un-upvote stuff from the past. The only use case is undoing a mis-click.

Here's what it looks like when you start to unupvote a comment:

[image]

Then if you try to upvote the same comment again:

[image]

Comment: You've also got to do it *after* the 5 second rate limiter otherwise it's locked in as well.

Comment: @Chris confirmed, if you get that message you can't un-upvote

Comment: @ChrisF I'll fix that for the next build.

Comment: *"You already upvoted this comment in the past and undid the vote, you can not upvote it again"* Um, I'm a schmuck for writing this, but: 1) run-on sentence; clauses should be separated with a semicolon or full-stop 2) missing terminating full-stop present in other pop-up messages 3) "*can not"* should arguably by "*cannot*".

Comment: Perhaps something like: *"You've already undone your vote on this comment; you cannot upvote it again."* There's no reason to say that you upvoted and undid the vote, because you obviously upvoted in order to undo the vote. That just makes the sentence more confusing.

Comment: @TheEstablishment I am going to need to add you to my skype so I can run "copy" by you... should be there next build

Comment: *"Once you un-upvote a comment you can not upvote it again."* So you are trying to discourage (puts on sun glasses) waffling? On a more serious note, should the 5 second timer be applied when un-marking a vote?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain no point really, cause you still need work through the alert

Comment: Erm...why is the 5 second timer there for unupvoting?

Comment: @Ben rate limiting, everything is rate limited

Comment: I don't understand why we need restrictions like this. I'm not going to make a game of upvoting a comment, undoing it, perhaps to consider it more, and then upvoting it again.

Comment: @Purmou I don't see why the 5 second delay is such a big deal ou are going to mistakenly upvote a comment once a year you can wait 5 seconds in such cases

Comment: If you concede that a user can accidentally click the upvote button and as a result needs to be able to undo it, doesn't it follow that the user may accidentally un-upvote and needs a way to upvote the comment again. This happened to me today and now I am unable to upvote the comment again.

Comment: I up-voted a fresh comment that was subsequently edited by the user into something with the opposite meaning. My initial vote was not an accident but now through no fault of mine, it's no longer the same comment I up-voted! Since the actual content of the comment was changed, there should be no restrictions on removing my vote, time limit or other.

Comment: Please increase the timeout to ∞ seconds.

Comment: What about the case where someone accidentally clicks on a comment's upvote, then un-upvotes it right away and then later, after actually reading it and giving it some thought, actually wants to upvote it. The second restriction will prevent that from happening. I concede that this probably doesn't happen often, but when it does, it could be pretty frustrating. I also agree with Sparky's comment: If a comment is edited, then un-upvotes should be possible. Conversely, if you un-upvoted a comment, and it is edited again, you should be allowed to upvote the edited comment.

Comment: What happens if the content of the comment was significantly edited after the 60 second limit, but before the 5 minute limit for editing?  Then it looks like you're agreeing with something that is rather different to what you upvoted for.

Comment: I dislike the implementation. I would like to be able to flip/flop especially if there is new information that warrants it.

Comment: I also found that if you up-vote accidentally, then click the arrow again to un-upvote, but decide to (or accidentally!) hit cancel instead of hit ok, you can't try to un-upvote again. Hitting cancel should be a no-op instead of counting as your choice.

Comment: @AaronBertrand the unupvote is available only as long as you did not refresh the page, once you refresh you can't undo the comment vote, no matter if you clicked the arrow before or not. Sam said that clearly: "provided you did not navigate away"

Comment: @sha I understand that. I've still hit that scenario a few times due to happy click fingers.

Comment: "nor do we want people to un-upvote stuff from the past"  **Why??**   Why are people forbidden from correcting their votes when they later realize they voted wrong?  There's no logical reason for locking things in like this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard is there going to be any addressing the concerns in these comments? Regarding the ability to flip-flop and also the feature of resetting the "has user voted" check if the comment is ever edited.

Comment: @Tyler not a dev but I am pretty sure the team will not change this behavior any time soon. You can start new feature request if you have specific idea in mind.

Comment: "You've already undone your vote on this comment; you cannot upvote it again."

I find this feature to be ridiculous. I clicked upvote, but my mouse is temperamental so it accidentally registered a click not once but thrice in rapid succession. This upvoted, unupvoted and confirmed the unupvote box. Now I can't upvote the comment, ever. There is no reason to limit the functionality of upvoting. Just terrible, terrible UI in my opinion.

Comment: what happens if user only knows this is not a good/correct comment after further research? e.g.: [See the top voted comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1240379)

Comment: does not work on m-site

Comment: This is surely the stupidest feature I have ever seen in my life.

Comment: Please stop being ridiculous and give us what we've asked for :)...

Comment: I am curious why this restriction applies to votes on comments but not to votes on questions or answers. "Because comments don't earn rep" or "because comments are less meaningful" have been given as justifications, but I'm afraid I still don't understand why.

Comment: "The only use case is undoing a mis-click." That should definitely not be the only use case, and even when that is the use case, having clicked the wrong comment, navigating away, and realizing it when you come back is still part of that use case. A user should be able to undo any vote they've cast that didn't result in an action being taken (e.g closing a thread) at any time.

Comment: If I navigate away, and the question is edited, and I look at it again, and I no longer think it should be closed as a duplicate, than what?

Comment: I don't understand why it should be harder to undo an upvote on a comment than on a question or answer. In my opinion, it should be the opposite. Votes on comments are relatively unimportant and don't change anybody's reputation, so there shouldn't be any limit on undoing comment upvotes.

Comment: it doesn't make sense to allow un-upvote for 60 seconds whereas editing is allowed for 300 seconds... I can only imagine that there are way more comments then answers/questions and to keep the system stable this was introduced... just guessing though... but why not just block the frontend? why not just say: "hey... just wait another 5... 10... 20... 40.... 80... whatever minutes before you try again"... seems old-style, but still works...

Comment: I’ve created a feature request [Allow un-upvote and re-upvote the comments as many times as user wants](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318568/allow-un-upvote-and-re-upvote-the-comments-as-many-times-as-user-wants)

Comment: "We do not want flip flopping, nor do we want people to un-upvote stuff from the past." WHY?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!? It *repeatedly* happens that I quickly click on the comment upvote, realize I might want to change my mind, and then have to panic to decide whether or not to let it *permanently* time out after *one minute*, or *permanently* undo my upvote. WHY THE H*** IS IT DESIGNED THIS WAY?! ***All this does is add stress to people's lives and add noise to the upvote counts.*** I am very frustrated.

Comment: The "ground rules" seem unwarranted. Why does this feature have arbitrary restrictions?

Comment: Really, who thinks of this. Just after 2 minutes, I found and realize I upvoted the wrong answer. I can't undo it at that time. instead of keeping the 1-minute process, what you can do is after two flip-flops user won't able to undo it. Eg: if user upvotes once by mistake we can consider a mistake. if user do that mistake again we will not consider as a mistake, we can consider as an intentional

Comment: I upvoted a comment by mistake, then immediately pressed again to un-do. After a while, readthe comment and wanted to upvoted but came across that error: "Once you un-upvote a comment you can not upvote it again."

Comment: Has this changed? I'm unable to remove an accidental comment upvote immediately after clicking.

Comment: I keep re-reading this to be sure I'm not missing something because it's so inane: "We do not want flip flopping, nor do we want people to un-upvote stuff from the past. The only use case is undoing a mis-click." Are you kidding me?! How does this ludicrous kind of thinking get this far unchecked?!  It is so narrow, illogical and unfounded.  Yes we want flopping on user input that a user later realizes is opposite from truth, of course I want that flipped back to what it should be.  WHY would I want GARBAGE DATA in one of the most useful tools on the planet!? Don't allow SO data pollution!

Answer (score 231):

I think this is important for long-term quality of the content. Comments are content; votes on comments are content as well.

Canceling votes *removes noise from the signal channel*.

Comment: And to make matters worse, I just then intended to Flag a comment for removal.. and my butter fingers instead upvoted it - this is not what I wanted! (I was using my iPhone at the time). This really should be changed! Or at the very least, have the flag button moved away from the upvote!

Comment: The only content we should really care about is the Q&A itself, the Comments are merely meant to help improve the Q&A. As for Phil Street we have this [separate feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104184/allow-flagging-a-comment-after-voting-it-up).

Comment: @TomWijsman, comments don't improve the Q&A as well when the upvote counts aren't correct because of clicking accidents. Just because they aren't as important as actual Q&A doesn't make them worthless towards the Q&A quality.

Comment: @BenLee: Incorrect. Comment voting leads nowhere; look here: [37 votes for a very useless comment, followed by a useful comment with only 2 votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15197/145350). The difference between 37 and 2 votes is really not by clicking accidents, hence comment vote counts *do not matter*...

Comment: I don't really follow your logic. How do intentional comment votes cancel out accidental comment votes? Anyway, it's not very important, just seems like it would a simple fix with no UI problem (a second click to cancel) that would make the site that much more user-friendly. But yeah, this is really low-priority so if it can't make the cut for updates, so be it.

Comment: Also, what makes that 37-upvoted comment useless? To me it seems like they made a good point.

Comment: @BenLee: You're making up intentional / accidental yourself as I haven't mentioned that. There is really no gain from being able to cancel an upvote on a comment, given that the upvotes are bogus anyway. Also, use an [@](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) when addressing people; or they'll read the response days to weeks later...

Comment: @TomWijsman, I'm aware of using @-targetting as you can tell my comment just above. I must have omitted by mistake the second time. Anyway, I am not making up the accidental/intentional distinction. That's the whole point of this post (being able to cancel out *accidental* upvotes)! If comment votes are always "bogus anyway" then what would be the point of having comment upvotes as a feature at all?

Comment: If comment editing is allowed then it also follows that removing accidental upvotes should be allowed for the same period.

Comment: @TomWijsman If they're completely useless, why not remove them entirely? They either have a function or not...

Comment: @TamaraWijsman your comment: "The only content we should really care about is the Q&A itself, the Comments are merely meant to help improve the Q&A." is so antithetical to the beautiful utility that is Stack Exchange.  Your comment indicates you do not understand it fully and may not be using it to its full potential.  Comments and upvoting have helped me solve countless problems and avoid countless mistakes.  To not have them would literally ruin Stack Exchange.  They need to be protected at all costs and further improved by allowing users to fix upvoted comments after gaining more knowledge.

Answer (score 177):

Whether a comment has an extra vote doesn't really matter, but if I go to click "offensive" and accidentally upvote instead, the flag button isn't available to me anymore. Again, an extra vote doesn't matter, but lacking a flag when needed does matter.

Comment: That's indeed a good reason. Maybe something to post as a bug?

Comment: This is now a feature request on its own: [Allow flagging a Comment after voting it up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104184/allow-flagging-a-comment-after-voting-it-up), @Shadow et al.

Answer (score 152):

It's funny that Jeff wrote [this post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/the-opposite-of-fitts-law.html) about bad UI and about accidentally clicking on a button, but in SO he won't change the functionality.

While not exactly contradictory, the upvote and the flag buttons are close enough together that this deserves more consideration.

Comment: yep I just hit this problem again, the browser was still finishing rendering and the Flag and Upvote comment buttons moved slightly causing me to upvote instead of flag. It's also a pain in the butt when browsing the site using a handheld such as an Android or iPhone.

Answer (score 22):

Yes. This needs to be done the same way as other voting, but it is not a huge priority in my opinion.

Answer (score 12):

While this would be nice, I give it an incredibly low priority because up votes on comments are nearly meaningless at this point. One or two random votes for a less than stellar comment aren't going to change the meaning of a discussion a great deal.

Comment: One nice effect of comment support is that it obviates the need for "I agree" comments - my sense is that there's less clutter of these since this feature was added.

Comment: @Argalatyr: I agree.

Comment: I agree that this is low priority, but still, it'd be nice to have and in my opinion it doesn't really have any downsides (other than time spent implementing it of course!).

Comment: It doesn't match user expectations. I can undo answer upvotes, why can't I undo comments? As for priority, it certainly won't stop earth from turning, but it *is* a missing functionality.

Comment: The problem is when you click on the vote icon, when you meant to click on the flag icon. Once you clicked on one icon, the other is not anymore accessible. I agree, it is probably a restricted case, but it still happens.

Comment: Wow, really?!: "because up votes on comments are nearly meaningless at this point".  I can't count the number of times I have been lead to good information or been made aware of bad information due to upvoted comments.  Obviously they're not perfect, but I believe they have saved me days or maybe weeks of time in my career!

Answer (score -6):

Focus should be more on maintaining the quality of discussion.

Upvoting and downvoting is just to attract others attention towards something that might be usefull.

Comment: And your point is? If you undo the comment upvote you can flag it just fine.