# Allow downvoting comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, down-votes, comment-voting

Answers and questions allow both upvoting and downvoting - comments, however, only allow upvoting.

I think it would be useful to allow downvoting of comments for two reasons:

- First, if you accidentally upvoted a comment you didn't intend to
- Second, if you strongly believe that a comment is [disparaging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15143/whats-with-all-the-rude-comments-recently), misleading, incorrect or off topic

Comment: Keep in mind, if you can downvote comments, they would have to implement an "edit comment" functionality to allow you to 'learn/rectify' the problem.

Comment: I agree. This is another useful feature that I think would benefit SO. I have actually deleted comments and them replaced them when I've realized that I made a misstatement or want to clarify what I meant.

Comment: I think comments should have downvoting, vote undo, editing, revisions, and community wiki. a.k.a answers

Comment: we do have "flag" for comments that are misleading, incorrect, etc; 'vote undoing' would be nice, however

Comment: @warren: unfortunately also [status-declined], but http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment

Comment: I would like to down vote the comment about the flag. It does **not** say "incorrect", the flag bubble help says "flag this comment as unconstructive, offensive or spam". The comment above is none of those it is just incorrect but I cannot express that without sidetracking the discussion about why his comment is wrong.

Comment: Please add this. There are some comments which bubble up higher than the ones that get less upvotes and this creates an imbalance.

Comment: I'm doing a lot of posting in the cryptography section, and especially in older posts there are a lot of completely misleading comments, and these include posts with upvotes (as many posters and voters are pretty clueless on the subject). Currently there is no way of telling people that a comment is wrong. I can comment myself, but the comment will only be shown if it has enough upvotes, which will never happen because the comment is never shown.

Comment: **Downvotes on comments = reputation loss** could be an interesting avenue to explore if downvotes are ever implemented. Forces users who care about reputation to come back and delete bad comments and motivates against doing it again (can also trigger auto-delete, but I think user action to keep reputation is a good idea, otherwise there's little motivation). It would be for those comments that don't quite qualify for being flagged, but shouldn't be there.

Comment: Personally, the only features I'd like to see added to comments are downvotes, automatic ordering of comments based on votes, lack of editing timeout, and removal of comment timestamps. Why? Because I have too much time on my hands, and want to be able to alter the chronology and context of comment conversations for personal amusement. Upvotes can turn what was sarcasm into helpful comment, and what was helpful comment into sarcasm. The comments section would become a meritocratic kakistocracy in microcosm. Completely unhelpful, sure... But worth it.

Comment: Downvoting makes me feel bad, it damages my self-esteem. It's like a slap in the face and running away. Downvotes make me *afraid* to participate in discussions. I don't want downvotes on comments.

Comment: @Calmarius: if you are afraid of downvotes rather than being wrong in a technical discussion, that sounds weird to me. The end goal should be to have useful comments, not incorrect ones. I see even high-rep users commenting things that are not correct in areas beyond their league. Perhaps, the reputation count misleads them about their skills. This is sad, and I see it repetitive. I would like to have consequence for that.

Comment: @LaszloPapp The problem is that downvotes are not helpful, not constructive. It's like masked strangers on the street saying "you suck" and run away. If somebody thinks I'm wrong, he should tell me why I'm wrong... The same applies for questions and answers. Those "People should explain downvotes" type questions come up often and rejected everyday with the reason that can be summarized in a sentence: "I'm too coward to give my name to my disagreement, but I demand an option to throw stones at you from hiding whenever I want, because it feels so good." Do we need this kind of behavior?

Comment: Vote undoing is already implemented. I upvoted one of the comments that was in favour of vote undoing and then, just to see what happens, clicked on the vote arrow again and was greeted with a dialogue box that asked if I really wanted to undo the vote (yes/no), so I clicked the Yes button, since I figure that there's no point upvoting a comment that asks for something that already exists. Like editing of comments, you probably only have a limited time to undo your upvote.

Comment: The downvote is a good idea... now please upvote me :)

Comment: How "*the question has not received enough attention*"? It has 22 answers!

Comment: @Pëkka " Wouldn't this be an "ideal" weapon for the community to battle rude comments" you could just flag the comment as offensive.

Comment: @user flagging is broken as a means of public moderation of rude and borderline content. See [make community comment moderation a more public process](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213694)

Comment: Absolutely need to be able to down vote comments.  On one of the sites there is an OP that got an early rep and not does nothing but enter negative comments or absolutes (wrong / right) with no reason like he is a king.  He does not answer any questions as he has been such a bully he knows he will get down voted.  I don't care if I lose 1 point to have him lose just 1 paint.  I want a way to say you are a bully and your comment is not constructive.

Comment: It's 2017, time to add missing feature. Upvoting comments is there, it means "many agree". Downvoting will be the way to say "many disagree" and comment author may delete it and maybe post a new comment, better one. Comments may contain rotten links or outdated information, there should be a way to downvote them. Flagging is different story.

Comment: It's a good thing comments can't get downvoted! 

Comment: It would be a good thing if comments could get downvoted! :)

Comment: "Second, if you strongly believe that a comment is disparaging, misleading, incorrect or off topic" Bud tis is what flaging koments is for.

Answer (score 129):

C'mon, people.  The upvotes on comments mean approximately nothing.  Let's have downvotes, too.  The more dimensions of pointlessness this site adds, the sooner somebody dies from forgoing food and sleep while using it.

In other words, sure, why not?  Plus, wasn't it [Jeff himself](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/the-value-of-downvoting-or-how-hacker-news-gets-it-wrong/) who said that only having upvoting represents only half the potential information?

Comment: I wasn't meaning to indicate that down-votes on comments were a bad idea, just that it had been covered before. I'll reword that part of my answer.

Comment: +1 especially for quoting jeff. I absolutely hate not being able to downvote.

Comment: Currently, there's no way to downvote comments that contain misleading or incorrect statements.

Comment: I want to also down vote comments that add no value.   "I have that same problem" deserves a down vote.  A correct comment that does pertain to the question deserves a down vote.  Since an up vote does not affect rep then neither should a down vote.

Comment: I posted a question today. The only response I've got so far is a snarky and unhelpful comment along the lines of "Your approach is completely wrong. I think there's a much better way of doing it," but containing no useful information about what a better approach would be. Three people have upvoted it. I wish I could downvote it.

Comment: @Blam (and Pete) Those comments should be flagged, not voted.

Comment: I agree with the last paragraph and disagree with what @devinb said in comment of the question. Down voting a comment will show value of the comment. You would not have to implement an "edit comment" functionality to allow you to 'learn/rectify' the problem as downvoting the comment would indicate disagreeing like upvotes indicate agreeing. As of this point, devinb has 66 upvotes on the comment. So, 66 agree, how many disagree? There is no value knowing how many agree without knowing disagreement levels as a balance

Answer (score 127):

If a comment is wrong, respond to it with another comment. That provides a lot more information than a downvote which could mean anything.

I completely agree with the "undo an accidental upvote" idea, but I don't see any much point in downvoting comments.

In terms of the value of upvoting comments: if a comment indicates that an *answer* is wrong, the upvotes on that comment indicate support for the reason given. They're almost like downvotes for the answer, IMO - just without rep getting involved.

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe the same could be said for up-voting, then. "If a comment is right, don't have up-voting. Leave another comment." On the other hand, votes could be considered a quick notation of "I agree/I disagree". It takes away from the noise of conversations like, "I have [whatever] suggestion... I agree... I like it... Good idea... Me, too... Ditto... No good... You're wrong... You suck... Shut up!" 'Just another way of looking at it.

Comment: There's an asymmetry between agreeing and disagreeing though: just saying "Me too" doesn't actually further the discussion. If you disagree, you have a *different* point of view, and therefore more information (your view). It's therefore a good idea to provide a comment when you disagree, but often that would just be redundant when you agree.

Comment: Upvoted comments are displayed first when there are too many comments to show at once. I would imagine sorting (or even hiding) downvoted comments could be a useful way of dealing with the signal to noise ratio of comments. I suspect people that have a strong disagreement with a statement of a comment are going to leave their own comment anyways. Downvoting comments could also be a useful means to track feedback on how people respond to a comment. Today the @user technique doesn't automatically notify you that someone made a remark about your comment (unless it's on your answer or question).

Comment: Hmm... notification of votes on comments would be potentially useful. I think the whole notification system needs careful consideration in general though.

Comment: *If a comment is wrong, respond to it with another comment. That provides a lot more information than a downvote which could mean anything.*

But then the same would be said of the questions and answers as well; eg “if an answer is not good enough or complete, instead of voting on it, post another answer providing more information”. What makes the questions and answers different from comments? The problem is downvote-and-runners. Downvoting is useful and even necessary, so long as the voters problem is explained.

Comment: @Synetech inc.: I'm not suggesting that someone shouldn't downvote - I think downvoting and commenting is entirely appropriate in many cases. And yes, I often *do* respond by writing another answer - but sometimes I don't know an answer which is *right*, I just know that the answer given is *wrong*. The difference between an answer and a comment is that an answer responds to a question; a comment responds to an answer (or potentially the question but in a non-answering way).

Comment: *The difference between an answer and a comment* - I meant voting-wise.

Comment: @Synetech: In that case, it's even easier - the difference is that you can't downvote a comment. But seeing as downvoting comments hasn't been mentioned, I'm still not sure what your point is.

Comment: *the difference is that you can't downvote a comment* - I meant the reasoning for the difference. *But seeing as downvoting comments hasn't been mentioned* - ??? The title of this whole page is **Should downvoting be allowed on comments?**

Comment: @Synetech: Whoops, yes - I'd become too focused on the details of my answer and the comments here.

Comment: @Jon: What’s the opposite of Ritalin? TV?

Comment: There's no anonymity in commenting!

Comment: @Michael, sure there is, log out; I’ve seen plenty of 1-rep drive-by users.

Comment: Responding to a bad comment may add more information, but it does so at the cost of adding *even more noise*. Also, if the comment occurred many posts ago in a comment thread, the original and the response can't easily be connected by a reader. Presently, I sometimes refrain from responding to clearly incorrect comments because I fear the noise I'd add is more harmful leaving the comment be. If a comment is patently idiotic, downvoting it (if such a thing were possible) would signal "no, this is wrong" to future readers without creating noise, and sometimes *more clearly* than a reply would.

Comment: Comments are meant so that there's no pressure of getting downvoted. Well not really that case but there are other reasons like asking for question clarification or if you have the same problem as them. That's why any rude comment will take a flag and it will count towards the helpful flags, good for a badge haha :)

Comment: +1 for "undo an accidental upvote"

Comment: Wouldn't a similar argument hold for questions and answers too? Don't downvote answers, argue by adding a comment.

Comment: @Unitato: I don't think there's as much benefit in terms of very quickly signalling value (positive or negative) of a comment as there is for a question or answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet I feel that comments can get a bit friendlier and helpful if the downvote was implemented, and there would be a lot less sarcasm and stuff.

Comment: @Unitato: I doubt it, to be honest.

Comment: I disagree with this and what @devinb said in comment of the question. You would not have to implement an "edit comment" functionality to allow you to 'learn/rectify' the problem as downvoting the comment would indicate disagreeing like upvotes indicate agreeing. As of this point, devinb has 66 upvotes on the comment. So, 66 agree, how many disagree?

Answer (score 79):

I'd also suggest that by having downvotes on comments, you're adding **symmetry** to the system, that is, treating comments in a similar way as you are treating answers and questions.  From a purely UI point of view, maintaining symmetry is a good thing to do; it reduces potential user confusion and increases ease of use.

Comment: Absolutely. It's nearly shocking that the functionality isn't currently present, based on the fact that upvotes on comments are allowed.

Comment: I, for one, was quite confused when I didn't see a downvote button for comments…at first, I actually thought it was just because of a reputation requirement!

Comment: Agree.  This comment should get a down vote as it adds no value.  If I agree then simply up vote the answer (which I did).

Answer (score 68):

Originally, I thought everyone was right - we don't need to complicate it.  But I changed my mind.

When the site first launched - 5 offensive tags would get a post removed.  Over time, even a non-offensive post would garner some flags, and since they weren't reset - as t => infinity every post would be deleted.  So a decay was added.

Comments now work the same way.  **Even a bad comment generates a few upvotes over time** and users have no way to indicate *no, this is a bad comment, it does not deserve upvotes.*  It may not be offensive, but it certainly doesn't contribute anything positive or funny.

So I think comment downvotes should be allowed in order to **make comments more worthwhile**.  It will help filter the *really good* comments the way God intended while leaving the poor comments - the ones people disagree with - "below the fold".

**Edit**: I know this topic is old and crusty but I'm *hoping* the system works, and that by edits and additions I can raise more awareness.

This is another example of why we need comment downvoting, from the Moderator flagged comment screen:
[Comment Flagging Example http://ritter.vg/misc/stuff/why-we-need-comment-downvotes.png](http://ritter.vg/misc/stuff/why-we-need-comment-downvotes.png)

It is *unreasonable* to make the claim that these comments are "noise, offensive or spam".  You may not *agree* with them, and whoever flagged them certainly didn't, but comments are flagged because we can't downvote them, and it adds a lot of noise to the Moderator screen, plus the necessity to go through and clear the flags.

Comment: Is that supposed to be an image there? All I see is a blue square with a question mark…

Comment: @BlacklightShining: Presumably it once worked, but the image has long since been moved or removed. (I'm guessing this was also before SE had its own built-in image uploader?)

Answer (score 41):

+1 I agree.

I've come across lots of situations where I think the wrong comments are standing out. They don't warrant a flag but there's no way to change what shows up without voting everything else up. It doesn't really make sense. Upvotes and downvotes are used to determine relative ordering of answers. I don't see why that doesn't apply to comment filtering too.

Answer (score 38):

In [Stackexchange podcast #3](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/se-podcast-03/) Jeff says that a lot of the comment flags aren't justified.

Maybe people flag because they can't downvote?

Answer (score 24):

> First, if you accidentally upvoted a comment you didn't intend to

I don't think you would need to downvote it - I think that there should be a similar click-to-undo feature like there is with up/downvotes on posts but downvotes wouldn't need to be there to cancel out an upvote

> Second, if you strongly believe that a comment is misleading, incorrect or off topic

If it's serious enough then you should flag it

Comment: Hmmm, I would never flag a comment that is incorrect or off-topic. (The tooltip states *"flag this comment as offensive, spam, or hate speech"*, and I assume this implies some human intervention as well?)

Comment: Yes, I agree, that's what I meant by saying "if it's serious enough" - sorry, should probably have made that more clear.

Comment: And I agree that an undo-upvote would probably do, if only to re-enable that flag button after one accidentally clicked upvote while aiming to click the flag button... On the other hand: this won't happen often, if ever, and others will surely flag the same comment regardless of my accidental upvote. So it might not be worthwhile the efforts.

Comment: +1 on this.  I accidentally upvoted a comment on a question (easier to do than you think because the buttons don't appear until you hover) and there is no way to take it back.

Comment: @Arjan van Bentem: Actually it says "flag this comment as **noise**, offensive, spam, or hate speech?" If its blatantly off-topic, flag it.

Comment: @voyager Yeah, given the rest of the site's UI, I've assumed a second click on the brighter up arrow would allow you to undo the upvote! And I've been using SO/MSO for 3 months!

Answer (score 19):

IMHO, comments provide a way to speak your mind freely; upvotes provide a way for other users to indicate their agreement without wasting space with a follow-up comment. But if you disagree, you really *should* post a follow-up comment...

If a comment really bothers you, you can flag it. Enough flags, and it'll be removed. This is more useful than down-voting, which would presumably leave a misleading or abusive comment visible.

There's some value in [keeping wrong answers around](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163730/when-should-i-delete-an-answer); even unhelpful ones can and are improved. But comments are ephemeral; they can't be edited outside of a short grace period, and shouldn't be the sole repository for important information. If a comment is *bad*, then it should be removed - not down-ranked.

Comment: I'm concerned about the most upvoted comments floating to the top, there's not really a way to disagree with an upvote other than not doing it

Comment: Post a comment that indicates *why* you disagree. Make a good argument, and your comment may well float to the top as well, augmenting or even replacing the one you respond to.

Comment: If you see a comment floating to the top that you don't agree with, post your own counter argument. Whether or not your comment gets voted up should show where other users stand on the issue.

Comment: That is a good argument, however, not everyone will take the time to write a good comment to accomplish that; I don't see why this couldn't get implemented though, you have downvotes on questions and answers in the end

Comment: I think the name itself is key to the... uh, *key* difference between comments and questions/answers: a comment is intended to provide *commentary* on a specific question or answer. Most comments don't really need to be voted on at all: their target audience is the author of the question or answer being commented on. Although it's possible to use comments for other purposes, or target them at other people (as i'm doing now...) the system does not make this easy... But it does recognize that, now and then, a comment may be useful to others: Up-voting provides a hint to the system in these cases

Comment: I disagree with leaving it to a flag.  If someone posts a negative comment, you cannot always respond to that otherwise you might start a discussion which could escalate.  Anyway, comments are not the discussion form of SO, they are a means of clarifying questions.  By allowing downvotes, we would be allowing "these type of comments are not appreciated on SO".  I don't have to get anyone's permission to downvote a question or answer, why should I need a mod's approval when flagging a comment?  BTW, I am writing this after having a flagged negative comment rejected, hence the paragraph.

Comment: @demongolem: if someone posts a flame-bait comment, it shouldn't be *down-voted* it should be removed. Would you really feel better knowing that an inflamatory comment caught 30 down-votes and 29 up-votes? As you say, these aren't meant for discussion - bickering and arguing can just as well be removed entirely.

Comment: As far as I’m concerned, this was the right answer lo these many years ago, and remains just as much the right answer today as on that ancient day when first it was written.

Comment: This  approach has consistently failed to work for me as a tool against the unconstructive, borderline rude (but not quite rude enough to flag) commentary that is so prevalent on SO. I'm not going to get into a comment war with every jerk beating up a hapless newbie. I just want to vote (hence signalling to the newbee that the comment doesn't stand there uncontested) and be gone. Why should what is a constitutional right on questions and answers, be totally unthinkable for comments?

Comment: Hahaha, I just saw we had the same conversation below a couple years ago.

Comment: @Shog9 `But if you disagree, you really should post a follow-up comment.` couldn't a similar thing be said about answers and questions as well?

Comment: Sure; if you're moved to post an answer that elaborates on the wrongness of a comment and provides solid details on a correct solution, that can be appropriate too in some cases @Pritt. I suppose even a follow-up question might be warranted at times. Don't get hung up on protocol; do what works.

Comment: Comments are not a way "to speak your mind freely". The purpose of comments is to improve the post, not to get into a discussion over the post.

Comment: I see you're into archaeology, @MaskedMan. Probably worth noting that neither TWP nor any of the other "subjective" sites existed when I wrote this answer; that said, the generally-adopted practice even on your home turf has been to ruthlessly *delete* comments when they go off the rails, which I still see as preferable to factional voting wars. Particularly for the sorts of rudeness that motivated this request in the first place, it's preferable to just be rid of them entirely.

Comment: @Shog9 The request was not motivated by rudeness (alone), a bigger problem is people posting answers as comments or [posting rubbish on other people's answers without reading it properly, which attracts downvotes](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5008/3192), because you have this other great feature of "hiding" the follow-up comments. I am not into "archeology", this post is referenced whenever someone complains about those issues. If you think it is no longer relevant, delete the answer or update it.

Comment: Also, it is good to know you finally realize that all sites do not work like Stack Overflow, perhaps it is time to take that up one notch and allow each site to customize the "software that runs the site", as well as implement some site-specific requests even if they don't make sense to Stack Overflow.

Comment: The advice I gave 9 years ago is just as valid now as it was then, @MaskedMan - if anything, flagging has become *more* important since then. (did you know there was a short period of time when 5K users could delete comments at will? Yeah, that... didn't work all that well)

Comment: @Shog9 Things would work out a lot better if you just change the link text to accurately describe what it is meant for. So rather than "add a comment", make it "suggest improvement". Then the OP can mark each such suggestion as "done", and those can be cleaned up by a scheduled job. It reduces the load on moderators to clean up lengthy discussions. But of course, SE just doesn't want to listen, they always have excuses for "why that won't work" instead of "how can we make it work".

Comment: Oh, you mean [like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299195/fixing-comments-in-5-minutes-intrigued-lets-discuss)? Or even [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256967/change-comment-to-critique-or-request-clarification)? Yeah, maybe some day.

Answer (score 18):

Looking at the discussion, the opponents of the possibility to downvote comments rely mainly on the following arguments:

1) If you don´t like a comment, you can comment yourself and explain

While this is certainly a good way to contribute to the discussion, it has often not quite the same power as downvoting a comment. Firstly, it may be that a lot of people have commented on a question/answer (and comments) so that your comment is not even recognized, even if you directly adress the commentator. Secondly, even if your comment is found directly below the critized comment, it might be overread by many people only looking at the top comment. On the other hand, a downvote is immediately recognized and the quality of the comment will be checked by people.

2) You can flag a comment you don´t like

This feels a little like throwing a bomb on the dove that soiled your car. Isn´t flagging for offensive or spam comments? This can not be applied to a lot of comments which one would like to downvote nonetheless, though.

3) It is redundant

Then upvoting comments certainly is redundant, too, as it does not change reputation. (Yes, I know there is a hard-to-get badge for so and so many great comments, but this has nearly no meaning IMHO). I have the feeling that comments might be a bit underrated. They are often a valuable part of the discussion and sometimes even replace a full-fledged answer.

Comment: When comments replace an answer, that is very bad. They can't be searched, can't be collaboratively-edited, and can disappear without a trace. If things of value flushed out in comment discussion don't get added to the post itself, there's a very real chance they'll do far less good than they otherwise could have. At their best, comments serve as sort of an "errata" section to answers; failing that, they're more or less disposable.

Comment: I speak only from my own experience, I see a lot of comments helping the OP to get on the right track. You are probably right, it would be a better way to post answers.

Comment: FWIW: you might like [this answer on Gardening's meta](http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/201/when-should-i-post-an-answer-and-when-should-i-post-a-comment/202#202) where a moderator there outlines some of the guidance he's given to users who have trouble deciding when to answer and when to comment.

Comment: @Shog in light of the Summer of Love discussion, has your position on this changed any? Being able to downvote a rude comment could be such a simple tool to improve the tone on the site, as nobody likes to be downvoted (except maybe Evan). As Gerald says, flagging often feels like throwing a bomb on the bird that soiled your car.

Comment: @Shog FWIW, http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142993/138112

Comment: @Pekka: eh... I'm not wild about it. Down-voting on answers can result in a negative score and a reputation drop - it's just enough of a sting to make folks care. Opinion-voting on content-free comments isn't likely to drive them off the page (you've been around Meta...) and attaching reputation to comment votes opens up a *huge* can of worms.

Comment: @Shog no, no rep loss. Just show a vote count on the comment. For everything egregious, you still have flagging. Voting would be to educate the "accidentally" rude people only, those who are productive but tend to be on the rough side occasionally - on the basis that people's threshold is much lower for downvoting something than to vote to destroy it.

Comment: @Pekka: to expand on my second point, the last comment I deleted had a score of 16. It was a link. That didn't apply to the post. If everyone who up-voted the question, answered the question, up-voted the answers, and posted correctional comments had down-voted it... It would *still* have been the most up-voted comment on the post. Without rep loss, there's no visible indication to the author that he's been voted on. I suppose you could create a custom "you've been down-voted!" notification, but that's pretty awful (and could just as well be done for flags).

Comment: @Shog but that's an extreme case. The idea is that flags stay for the extreme cases. Votes would be there to say, "don't be such a jerk."

Comment: @Pekka웃: except a down-vote *doesn't* say that. Well, I guess we could convert down-votes into inbox messages that read "don't be such a jerk" but then why not just cut to the chase and post... a comment reply. Perhaps one that conveyed the desire for less jerkish behavior in a less jerkish fashion. I donno... Kinda thinking it makes more sense to just expose comment flags to 10K users and accelerate the deletion of *actual* crap.

Comment: @Shog I'd really like to see *some* way to tell the world, "that dickhead comment over there doesn't represent the general tone of this entire community". Either through public flags or comment downvotes.

Answer (score 14):

Sounds like a reasonable addition to me.

Comments were really **designed to be a light-weight mechanism** to communicate some ancillary information about the post. But I see the comment system on Stacks evolving out its **2nd-class status** into a more robust part of the contribution process... for a few reasons:

- Sometimes the **comments posted are awesome** and such a high-quality part of the question/answer process, that it simply needs to be recognized as a bigger contributor to the system.
- Some topics simply call for **more ingrained collaboration** of people to help the process of formulating a more thorough answer.
- And the business/social-hosting reasons I discuss here: [Could Stack Sites Ever Seamlessly Incorporate More Collaboration/Discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3248/could-stack-sites-ever-seamlessy-incorporate-more-collaboration-discussion)

Answer (score 14):

I really like that when an answer gets enough downvotes it gets lightened.  That's a good deterrent against people giving annoying answers.  I'd love to see the same system (downvoting a few times make the comment lightened out) as deterrent for borderline troll types.  Flagging and deleting is too blunt an instrument.

Answer (score 12):

I'm against it for a reason that I believe hasn't been mentioned yet, but I also will present a compromise.

While the difference of up- and downvotes is a useful indicator for the quality of a post, the number of upvotes alone is also. That is simply because often people are strongly disagreeing with each other.

On top of that, a downvote is often given not because a post isn't useful or even inappropriate, but merely because people didn't like it. When emotions run high, it can even deteriorate into a mere tug-of-war between two mobs. Given that the term *disparaging* is already in the question this scenario is already in the room.

During controversies, seeing both votes is most useful, only positive votes second, and the difference is the least useful of all options.

In fact in such situations seeing the standard deviation could be a better indicator than the difference, an indicator I often use to gauge the potential value of literature or movies on Amazon or imdb.

For posts on SO, those arguments apply rarely, but even on SO controversies do frequently occur in comment sections, so in those cases displaying a difference only may be harmful.

YouTube, for example, has such a voting system and suffers from the phenomenon of voting mobs trying to vote an enemy into obscurity (I presume that the proposal is to keep having a comment's score influence its prominence as it does now).

Disqus, on the other hand - a discussion system often used on blogs - shows both up- and downvotes, and in the face of controversies, it so manages to allow all sides of an argument to live while still displaying interesting posts more prominently.

I understand that SO isn't a political blog, but there are still arguments, and people are as irrational when feeling attacked here as anywhere else. In that light I feel that such a proposal would increase bad blood.

A compromise could be to display the difference but use only the upvote count to determine how prominent the comment is placed (ie. wether it will be visible before one clicks *show all comments*). That would take a significant amount of incentive away for voting people down to silence them while still showing the average visitor sentiment.

Comment: Very well thought out. A both diplomatic and logical answer.

Answer (score 11):

The real question to me is "***what does an up-vote on a comment really mean?***"

I've always felt that it just implied somebody else was feeling it, and was giving you props...  It really has nothing to do with reputation and ability to add witty comments doesn't imply you know how to code...

So with that said, I don't think this is necessary.

If it were to be implemented, then does a downvoted comment affect your rep?  Does casting a downvote affect your rep?  If you can get punished, should an upvoted comment give you rep?

Overall, I say no to this...

Comment: So a downvote would indicate that you were feeling against it.

Comment: It means "I agree" with the sentiment expressed in the comment.  It means "I second that."  And it also means "I like that or it made me laugh."

Answer (score 9):

I think when enough people upvote an obnoxious answer other people may think this is true or a good idea. I see many of those and i really wish to express my disagreement. I would like comments with an up and down count so we can see how many ppl agree and disagree and not just get a average number ((agree count, disagree count) > (result = agress - disagree))

Answer (score 9):

I believe you should be able to downvote comments, because the number next to a comment can often be taken as a poll on the popularity of the sentiment expressed, with no balancing, quick way to gauge the level of support for the opposite idea.

Take a practical example that I just ran into and caused me to look up comment downvoting here: I posted a question on another SE site that quickly received a comment about the long windedness of it. Within a few minutes, it had 2 upvotes already. In response, I posted an explanation that my actual question was obvious early on and that I was merely providing further details for those who wanted them.

Now for those taking just a quick glance at the responses, it looks like 2 people agreeing with the first comment and a bunch of my (long winded, heh) comments arguing against it. Other people actually have to take the time also to argue against it with their own comments (which is more time consuming than the effort invested by the upvoters), and even then, the original upvote count could give the false impression of a more popular support than might otherwise exist.

I'll play devil's advocate here though: If a valid counter argument exists, at least one person should take the time to respond with it in a new comment. Others can then quickly upvote this new comment and have its numeric tally stand against that of the original comment.

Oh boy. I might have just invalidated my own argument ;)

Answer (score 8):

I just want to be able to downvote the meta-comments.  Flagging them as noise has not proven effective.

Comment: All comments are meta.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Does that make comments posted on a `meta.*` site meta-meta?

Answer (score 8):

Here is why I think down-voting comments could be a good idea.

I have just experienced a **flame war** in the comments section. A lot of answers here are arguing that a simple counter-comment is more useful than a down-vote. However, counter-comments can also lead to arguments over the two opposing views. By being allowed to down-vote, people could register their disagreement in a way that does not court argumentative discussion.

Comment: the right way to handle "flame war in the comments section" is to [flag it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7016/165773) for attention of moderator (who typically will remove all the comments involved in that war)

Comment: @gnat While that's true, it would also deprive future readers to analyze the subject of controversy in detail.

Comment: @Unitato Stack Exchange model is [not for discussing and analysing controversies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773) - these are rather heavily discouraged and have their place outside, in multiple discussion forums on the web. Depriving users from misusing the site is a good thing. As they say in [tour], "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum."

Comment: Yes!  This - DVs on comments would put a stop to a lot of comment bickering and flame wars.  It's been ten years.  We need to reconsider, I think.

Answer (score 7):

My understanding was always that up-votes on comments was intended to be a way to represent the fact that multiple people would have written that same comment, essentially, it would prevent "me too" comments.

I came to this understanding due to the way automatically-generated comments from the review queues worked.  Certain reviewing actions would leave a comment on a person's post.  If another person had already performed the same action, instead of leaving a comment, it would up-vote the existing comment.

If this is the case, than the vote count on a comment isn't so much it's score as it is the number of people who also wanted to leave that same comment.

If we allowed down-votes on comments, it would undermine that paradigm.

Comment: Canned review comments are a workaround, and shouldn't be the basis for the entire comment system. While you highlight an edge case, canned review comments represent a very small minority of comments overall.

Comment: @TravisJ  It's not so much that they're the basis for the comments system.  It's more like they're evidence that the comments system is that way

Comment: They are evidence of that process being used in a nanoparticle of the system, but not evidence of the way the entire system works. "This comment adds something useful to the post" is the text for the upvote. There should be a "This comment is not useful" space for voting there as well, since the commenting system as a whole is used as a place to produce content, albeit sometimes either tangential or supplementary.

Answer (score 5):

Just mentioning [undoing a comment upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1170/147650) has now been implemented, for immedate undoing anyway.

Answer (score 4):

It's important to consider why a comment should be downvoted. Is it rude? There already is a "mark as unconstructive". Is it not *that* rude? Maybe it shouldn't be downvoted then.

Is it being downvoted for inaccurate information? Follow up comments can correct it, and then the real information should be added to an answer if the information is actually worth mentioning.

Comment: A comment being rude, but not rude enough for flagging, is *exactly* the use case for a downvote.

Comment: The problem is, for every time I mark something as unconstructive because it is sure purely obviously rude and unhelpful, there are at least 15 people who upvoted it because they found it funny.
Downvoting rude comments would be struggling against a tide. Unfortunately, the ones I marked as unconstructive don't get approved (possibly *because* of all the upvotes)

Comment: the threshold to downvoting a comment would be much, much lower than to flagging it. I'm sure that if the feature were available, we would find much different dynamics.

Comment: What about a comment that expresses a certain viewpoint, and you disagree with it? You cant say its offensive, or nonconstructive, then why not downvote?

Comment: Then you run into the problem of downvoting having so many subjective meanings that the poster of the comment has no idea what the votes are communicating. Plus, if you disagree but it is an otherwise friendly helpful comment, it makes more sense to upvote it and state your disagreement - and reasoning - in a follow up comment. If someone already posted your disagreement in a comment, then upvote the disagreeing comment. Using voting can accidentally reduce dialogue (i.e. "I disagree with your reasoning because...") that brings value to everyone, including third parties.

Comment: One of the greatest ways to grow in skill is to have people disagree with you *and explain why*.

Answer (score 3):

Questions and Answers are the core information parts of the site. Comments are an addition to *assist* Questions and Answer, and while they are important in many ways, they shouldn't become complicated.

I think comments have become more important over the years, some really good information in them, but moreso from their ability to provide clarification of a problem in an answer or question (and as a result discussions about information in another comment).

But their being useful comes in part from their simplicity.

An upvote on a comment allows people to say "I agree with this" and "me too" (etc) helping reduce potential noise from their otherwise posting duplicated comments. However, just because comments have an upvote to state people agree and/or something is valuable and should be noted by others, does not mean that downvotes would bring about more accuracy or usefulness.

With comments being simple little things, not agreeing means don't upvote the comment, if you disagree strongly enough then write another comment. This works well and I think complicating them with downvotes not only dilutes this already useful process, but adds layers of complexity.

1. Do we arrange comments from net votes or up votes
2. What about the potential loss of focus on answers now we can vote comments up and down
3. "hey who downvoted my comment"
4. People will start wanting more features now there's up and downvotes, like stats, a requirement to edit because people can downvote them

Too much faff would come from it, and comments then become less simple as a means to leave a "note".

The current setup encourages both sides of the debate to be shown as people will voice the alternative opinion(s). Whereas with up and down votes on comments, all you see is the net result, and that as we know from answers isn't a great indication of the general opinion. A net of 5 could be from hundreds up and down, or 6 up and 1 down, etc.

So with net votes from having up/down votes on comments, we end up with the problem that people might agree with it and upvote because they don't have the contradictory comment giving them other ideas. This has a potential for the [Bandwagon Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwagon_effect) so it ends up having a high net upvote count that is not really a good representative of the quality or accuracy of the comment.

Whereas without downvotes, people are more inclined to voice the alternative opinion and that comment gets upvoted instead, and/or the other comment doesn't get upvoted anymore.

Answers are not an example to debate this as they have completely different characteristics to comments. It's the information and debates in comments themselves which can influence voting in answers and questions, if we introduce downvotes to comments where do we discuss the comments...

Comment: "The current setup encourages both sides of the debate to be shown as people will voice the alternative opinion(s)." To the extent that this works, it's actually a *bad* thing, since it increases the amount of verbose back-and-forthing that amounts to nothing permanent but requires a lot of wading through, the very thing SE was created to eliminate. But since comments are filtered by score without regard to replies, it actually *doesn't* work: comments tend to get shown with inadequate context, and the more popular side of the debate can often be the only one initially visible.

Comment: @NathanTuggy "*the more popular side of the debate can often be the only one initially visible*" but generally this is the side we want to be shown, the more correct one. Sure bad info can be more visible due to upvotes, but there's never a perfect way and this seems to work "well" from my experience in general. Comments with good info are "generally" upvoted, and comments with bad info are  counter commented and that one is upvoted. It wont work well all the time, sites are too big with many things going on. If you have potential improvements they should be made public.

Comment: My point was that the very thing you're touting as an advantage of the current system isn't always an advantage, and frequently *causes* the very problem you say it helps avoid ("we end up with the problem that people might agree with it and upvote because they don't have the contradictory comment giving them other ideas. This has a potential for the Bandwagon Effect so it ends up having a high net upvote count that is not really a good representative of the quality or accuracy of the comment.")

Comment: If I had some awesome magical way to fix all the problems with the current comment collapsing setup, sure, I'd go ahead and post that. But just because I don't yet know how to *solve* the problem doesn't mean I can't point out that there *is* a problem, or that the problem messes up current crude approaches to other problems that could be improved (e.g., the upvote-only approach that is the subject of a suggested improvement through this question).

Comment: "*just because I don't yet know how to solve the problem doesn't mean I can't point out that there is a problem*" I agree, but the fact you (and I/others) don't have a better solution and factoring in that a perfect one is likely impossible, viewing the current way as "works ok" isn't such a problem. It might not be perfect, and has some flaws, but I think those flaws are mostly due to the nature of catering for multiple conflicting requirements - something's gotta give.

Comment: Sure, but the answer argues that adding downvotes to comments would *create* a problem that, in fact, already *exists*, and would work against a benefit of the current situation that is, in fact, actually a drawback.

Answer (score 1):

Comments are used to quickly exchange short bits of information. I believe it was concluded that it wasn't necessary to use a full blown voting system on them, especially since comments that were voted up will float above the less useful ones in the previews.

Also votes on comments don't contribute to rep anyways, so downvoting on them would feel redundant. It should be clear if something in the comment is incorrect when other comments around it are voted up. Also as @Shog9 said, if there is something completely off about a comment you can flag it.

Comment: Well, the ability to vote them up is what makes me think about why I can't vote them down

Answer (score 1):

I am concerned that allowing downvotes would contribute in a negative fashion to the introduction of new users to the site.

Many times, comments are the communication mechanism that is used to guide users to read the faq or guide the new user to post in a different way.

I think it is inevitable that new user's comments during this back-and-forth would be downvoted heavily at times, when it would be better to guide them in a neutral-or-positive fashion towards the faq.

Comment: I think the opposite might be  the case - comment downvotes could help with those abrasive, borderline rude comments that litter every newbee question on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Completely agree with Jon Skeet here. If a comment is rude, wrong, irrelevant, or any number of other things that may offend you, simply respond with another comment stating your discontent.

That's the functionality of a comment, to sustain a constructive conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Completely agree—since we have upvoting of comments, we should have downvoting too.

As things stand, a comment may have, say, 9 upvotes, giving the impression there is strong support for it in the community. Whereas in fact there may be 18 or 118 people who strongly disagree with the comment, so it should show a negative total.

This is terrible! It would be better not to have any voting on comments than to have this one-sided, misleading picture.

Comment: To be honest I like that we only have the ability to upvote comments. Many times I have seen a highly voted comment which I don't agree with, along with a responding comment with an even higher vote count which has a better argument. So this design has the benefit of singling out interesting discussions which help improve or explain the post being discussed. So if there is a comment which a lot of people disagree with, sure enough someone will respond and all those people can upvote the responding comment.

Comment: @KodosJohnson that's certainly true. However, that can always happen, independently of any downvoting of comments. And besides, usually it's not that straightforward: these things take place over time, sometimes a long period of time. Realistically we can't follow every single post so as to be aware of all comments at all times. And we can't reply to a comment, we can only _add_ a comment; by then, other comments may well have been added on other matters. We can name the comment poster by way of replying lower down, but then there is no visual immediacy for those seeing the upvoted 
comment.

Comment: In all network sites, comments with low vote counts are hidden by default if there are many comments. If there is a highly voted comment responding to another comment, it is insightful to me to see what they were responding too. If the original comment is downvoted to oblivion, I have to really dig to find it. Having all the conversation featured prominently makes it easy to read at a glance.

Comment: That's not to say you don't have good points though. To me it's just that you have to take the good with the bad and IMHO the good outweighs the bad.

Answer (score -2):

I think it should be permissible, but with no rep change for the action (and make it undo-able always). The lack of rep change will help negate some of the fear of downvotes in that area.

In a slightly off-topic note: I also feel that the comments should be editable for more than the five minutes after posting it. It is easy enough to post them that it is easier to post another than to edit a current one within the five minutes, anyways.

Answer (score -4):

You can already flag why would you downvote. Comments aren't meant to mean anything(no rep). Upvoting is more for it showing up before the rest.

Comment: The lack of comment downvotes is problematic because many comments [retain their upvotes even if they are unpleasant or objectionable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15143/whats-with-all-the-rude-comments-recently).

Answer (score -4):

I want to add another reason for implementing downvotes on comments.

I see a lot of low quality comments recently and it feels like some people don't even think before they comment. Adding downvotes to comments would allow to manage all these low quality comments, useless "Thank you!" comments, and out-of-context conversations.

Comments should be handled similarly to answers and get deleted after they received a certain amount of downvotes.

Comment: You can just flag those kind of comments as 'No Longer Needed'.

Comment: Those example comments were gone with one flag. No down votes needed ...