# Ability to downvote comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should downvoting be allowed on comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments)

And if it's declined: Is there a reason this is not supported?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615