# Undo your upvote to comments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments

Can't undo upvote on comments. The comments area understandably has a small interface and I accidentally upvoted the wrong comment. Apparently they cannot be un-upvoted.

Comment: Although you only seem to have a few minutes to un-upvote a comment. It's happened on several occasions now where I've upvoted a comment very soon after it has been posted. However, the OP has then edited their comment - to which I received no notification or visual indication (as there were no additional comments) - and had completely changed the meaning of their comment. I would have retracted my upvote if I could but unfortunately my upvote was now stuck, showing support for a statement that is utterly wrong.

Comment: The referred request was to limit time to un-vote for 1 min, but this request is to not restrict it at all.

Comment: This question may be considered as a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49633/no-way-to-remove-accidental-upvote-on-a-comment, but not [currently linked 1 min limit permission](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/cancelling-upvote-on-comment?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 16):

Oh, no!  Now you'll have to forever bear the shame of having anonymously upvoted a comment, which has little to no impact on anything whatsoever!

Seriously, though, I agree with you.  It's not high on my list of complaints (why am I *still* unable to remove a vote to close), but it's on there somewhere.

Comment: I think the remove a vote to close is more important...

Comment: Oh, shoot.  I didn't mean to upvote that comment :P

Comment: `little or no impact` - yeah that's why they implemented the feature.

Comment: I use upvotes as a reminder to my future self that the comment adds to the answer. If further down the line I realise that the upvoted comment is wrong, it leaves a wrong message (to me and to anyone looking at a highly upvoted comment). So I wouldn't say it has little to no impact.

Answer (score 7):

On a similar note, I wish there was a way to downvote a comment.

If a commenter puts "the best way to access elements in the HTML page is to use document.all" I can't downvote this.  I can post a comment pointing out why it is wrong... and hope for upvotes... but the comments were never designed to support a hierarchy... thus later when someone sees the "minified" comments (based on votes) all they see is a rant that has nothing to do with the original question / answer. :-(

Comment: I sort of disagree... because it works well enough now, and I wouldn't want to complicate the UI. Bad comments *usually* get shot down by a follow-up comment with many upvotes. (What you say about the "minified" view is true though...)

Comment: By the way, there's a request about this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments. And another one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7014/ability-to-downvote-comments

Comment: @Jonik "because it works well enough now" - the everlasting argument of the mediocre ;)