# We should be able to vote comments down as well as up

Tags: feature-request, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should downvoting be allowed on comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments)

If comment to a question or answer is nonconstructive but doesn't warrant being flagged, there should be a way to indicate this to the author by giving the comment a negative vote.

Comment: Duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments

Answer (score 2):

Overall I would not mind if comments could get voted down, at least it would be a better indicator of it's popularity than just counting upvotes, but in the grand scheme of things it is definitely not required.

Comment: Or at the very least let me take away my upvote if I mis-click...

Answer (score -1):

No.

In my opinion, anyway. Comments are sweet little extras. They might contain helpful or agreeable things (then go and vote), but if they don't, that's totally fine.