# Allow us to cast thumbs down on comments

Tags: feature-request, comment-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should downvoting be allowed on comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments)
>   [We should be able to vote comments down as well as up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9075/we-should-be-able-to-vote-comments-down-as-well-as-up)

Sometimes there are incorrect comments that have gained enough thumbs up in the past that they seem like good suggestions while they are in fact wrong or even dangerous practices.

I *really* wish there were thumbs down on comments, so we can see how many people disagree with them and actually have a chance to balance the score.

Comment: What does this look like, YouTube? ;)

Comment: +1 I like this too... but in a SO way ( which I don't know really what would be, but not exactly as YouTube )

Comment: Oscar Reyes: I think 2 numbers, upcount and downcount would be interesting and not just a number by adding +1's and -1's

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write a comment in response that disagrees, which others can then upvote.

Comment: And start the flame???

Comment: Expressing disagreement is not flame war.

Comment: @Jon B: Its just the beginning of one.

Comment: All flame wars begin with a disagreement, but not all disagreements end in flame wars. (Unless you're talking about the Internet. We're not on the Internet, are we?)

Comment: No, we are in Ponyland. Were disagreements are solved with Waffle eating contests. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URsqTsMfNqY