# Please let us downvote comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should downvoting be allowed on comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments)

Why can we downvote questions and answers, but not comments? They often deserve it.

Comment: Right. Wonder why this didn't come up in Related Questions...