# Should comments have the possibility of being voted down?

Tags: feature-request, questions, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should downvoting be allowed on comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments)

People can answer a question with a comment and they can be voted up but not down. Someone just answered something (in the comment section) and was upvoted 4 times but is downright wrong.

Should comments have the possibility of being voted down? Or shouldn't it be a sort of flag, not for "spam" but for 'this is an answer not a comment'?

Comment: I think it's a definite problem because comment upvotes can be traded in for epic mounts and new weapons.  Also, this answer is incorrect, but you're going to upvote it anyway.  Mwahaha!  My not-really-thought-out master plan is complete!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voting a comment up does nothing. So who cares if they get voted up?

Comments != Answers, this should be very clear.

The proper thing to do in this situation is to reply to the comment and state why you think the comment is wrong, and ask the person to remove it.