# Are most people here also regulars on SO? I get the feeling they are not

Tags: discussion

I don't understand. Reading through the comments and answers I get the feeling that most people on Meta are not the same people on SO.  People on this site seem very mean spirited as opposed to those on SO.

Is it because there are too many "dumb" questions, this site is made up of complete a-holes?

Comment: What is this "SO" place?

Comment: SO stands for expert-sex-change.  It is a website where you can go to get really lost in adds.

Comment: One thing to take note of, if you're trying to characterize other people as being rude and inconsiderate, it's not the best idea to wander into their midst and call them all "complete a-holes"

Comment: @devinb: To be fair, I've been called worse.

Comment: @devinb: actually, seems like a *great* way to bring out the worst in whoever you're addressing...

Comment: Actually, I'm an NP-complete a-hole.

Comment: @Shog - *whomever*, you ignorant git. `:P`

Comment: @Eric: You're not only a complete a-hole, you're a partial b-hole, too.

Comment: tv, that was so nerdy and so awesome. I declare you winner of the thread.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Not rigorous enough.  You have to show how another NP-complete a-hole can be reduced to you.

Comment: Wait... I just realized. The "question" is unclear. Are you pro or anti "assholism"?

Comment: @tvanfosson: If you can prove that you are also a P a-hole, there's a million dollars in it for you.

Comment: @Bill -- in college I applied for a job as a traveling salesman. QED.

Comment: you are all my niches

Answer (score 13):

There's a big difference in what is being discussed on the different sites. For the regular sites, it is definitely important to stay polite and impartial because you are supposed to be answering questions.

On Meta, there is a lot more discussion concerning the future of the sites and how the community should operate. This is when you start introducing opinions and that is when people will start going toe-to-toe on issues, and often times people will take more offense at this conflict than they would about a disagreement over whether 2+2 really equals 4.

On Meta, opinions matter highly, and it is also an avenue for a lot of us to be more vocal and laid back and not have to feel so "professional". I agree that this is not an excuse to be a blatant asshole, but I consider this site a lot more like the "teacher's lounge" where Mr. Johnson and Mrs. Crabtree can smoke and drink their coffee and not have to be the perfect role models that they have to be in front of the students.

Comment: 2+2=5.  I always use very large values of 2.

Comment: @squillman: You are wrong. And your mother is fat.

Comment: Oh god we're falling into the trap again!

Comment: **Ponies Suck!**

Comment: "where Mr. Johnson and Mrs. Crabtree can smoke and drink" - We can smoke and drink here?!?  Why didn't I know about this before now?

Comment: @jjnguy: +1 for analogy fail

Comment: Analogies are like old barns: They always fall apart at some point.

Comment: Wait, so we're not supposed to drink and post on SO? Whoops...

Comment: @mmyers iseewhatyoudidthere

Comment: You jackasses. Now my clothes smell like smoke.

Comment: @TheTXI: you're going to make me cry

Comment: @Shog9: That's because we were burning them. Unclear requirements...

Comment: 10 + 10 = 100

Comment: 2 + 2     = Jello

Answer (score 5):

I think some people just let loose a little more here. Since this site isn't about programming so much, there's less incentive to keep it professional.

With that said, I still refrain from insulting comments. However, I am more likely to post nonsense here than I am on SO. I think that goes for several others as well (at least the nonsense part). I can't think of anyone in particular who posts nonsense, though (**cough**).

Comment: Very true...I try to be nice on SO.

Answer (score 5):

I would view the "rude comments" here with a grain of salt.

Users here *are* regulars on the other sites but, more to the point, they are regulars *here*. I would say that, oh, 90% of the rude-appearing comments you see here are just community-member "regulars" participating in on-going, sometimes-inside jokes... trading in little quips, and barbs, and a bit of [one-upmanship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-upmanship).

Harmless, mostly.

<sub>Then again, some people are just itching to be annoying.</sub>

Comment: And some people are just itching. I knew I shouldn't have gone into the deep grass yesterday...

Comment: I always win in the one-up contests btw.

Comment: It should also be noted that if programmers aren't given a proper outlet to be snarky, their heads will explode in a cloud of confetti.

Comment: @jjnguy: no you don't.

Comment: @TheTXI: That's nothing! My confetti will explode in a cloud of heads!

Comment: I've beaten jjnguy in a one-up contest.

Comment: I hate fine print. It's just annoying. What does it say?

Comment: Oh Meta...I would get way more work done without you around...

Comment: @devinb "Then again, some people are just itching to be annoying."

Comment: "What's it say!? I can't read!!"

Comment: *She studied it carefully for about 15 minutes. Finally, she spoke. "There's something written on here," she said, frowning, "but it's really teensy."* --
[Dave Barry, "The Columnist's Caper"]

Comment: (I happened to have http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html open in another tab right now.)

Comment: At jinguy, you don't understand sarcasm at all do you. Not even a little. Such a sad pathetic, itchy, annoying life you must lead.

Comment: At devinb - I prefer to err on the side of helpful on the internet.  I just picture you as an 80-year-old man squinting at the monitor.

Comment: I'm none of those things! Well... "at the monitor" I suppose. "pictured" I suppose. "Helpful" I certainly am. "err" I certainly don't. "devinb" that accurately names me. "the internet" I wouldn't consider myself.
What was I saying?

Comment: I'm not sure where you were going with that...

Answer (score 3):

I think most people don't take meta seriously, or at least don't assign the same value as they do to SO.

Examples of this are all the problems with people migrating here stuff that [doesn't belong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13047), [increase of sarcasm and bad manners](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15143), etc

And since they can't be funny or rude on the other sites, they come here (wrongly) to vent

Comment: I take Meta way too seriously.

Comment: The first link isn't an example of what you are saying.  It is Jeff saying that desktop things don't belong on serverfault.

Comment: "most people"

Comment: @jjnguy, fixed link

Comment: Anyone who doesn't take meta seriously should be shot out of a cannon into a wall, and then shot.

Comment: With the same cannon?

Comment: With actual cannons.

Comment: Cannon-shooting cannons?

Comment: Who would prime the inner cannons?

Comment: other people, shot out of other cannons?

Comment: Cannons don't shoot cannons. Humans shoot cannons.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we are the same people, but not always with the same name.  I am Rich B over on SO.

Comment: And I am btk on MSO.

Comment: And I'm the Easter Bunny.

Comment: And Welbog is the Queen of England. -- mmyers

Comment: And Welbog is mmyers. -- The Queen of England

Answer (score 1):

Lots of people are regulars on the other sites.

For the most part, the people on Meta are also regulars on one of the SO family sites.

Some of the time you get people asking questions that aren't regulars, but everyone answering is very familiar with how things work.

Answer (score 1):

Many of us are regulars on SO. I apologize if you've been met with negativity here. Since this is the meta-forum, people are much more laid-back and less-reserved to bite at eachother.

Comment: Laid-back means more rude? I always thought it was the opposite.

Comment: @mmyers: Look at it this way...who would you be more likely to call a raging homo...your best friend while watching football on a Sunday afternoon, or your boss?

Comment: @TheTXI: No.

Comment: An apology isn't an answer!

Comment: @TheTXI: I don't think either of them would say "raging"

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do to figure out if their regulars to the other sites, is to check their accounts tab.

```
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/{userid}?tab=accounts
```

---

Most of the accounts that I have looked at, have more rep elsewhere.

Comment: How in the hell did you score such an awesome `userid`? Well done!

Comment: Right place at the right time, I guess.

Comment: I only wish I had been so lucky on S[UF].

Comment: Most. What do you have to say for the sad pandas who have Meta as their highest?

Comment: When your meta rep is the highest of all the other accounts, you're spending way too much time thinking about `S(O|F|U)`

Comment: Actually if you looked, you would notice that I got over 2k, in just two months on Meta. While it took 6 months to get that high on Stack Overflow. At that rate, I'll have 10k on Meta, before I even get to 5k on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can feel the love everywhere.

[**Whats With All The Rude Comments Recently**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15143/whats-with-all-the-rude-comments-recently)