# Don't let me click an undelete button if the question can't be undeleted

Tags: feature-request, questions, moderation, undelete, vote-to-undelete

So it seems that when a question has been deleted by a moderator, [it's not coming back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77107/lock-posts-by-default-when-deleted-by-a-moderator/86481#86481). Whether or not one agrees with that, it would be nice if such a post ([example, requires 10k natch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305290/finding-nearest-vertex-of-a-parallelogram-to-a-random-spot-in-that-parallelogram)) didn't even *have* a clickable undelete button, rather than tempting the user with a button which *first* `alert()`s, *then* goes off to the server, ***then*** [says no](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_says_no).

Maybe it should have a struck-through <strike>`undelete`</strike>, with appropriate tooltip, a la [my favourite answer to the dual question about deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15535/please-dont-show-delete-when-a-question-cant-actually-be-deleted/15537#15537).

*edit* updated question to suggest disablement, rather than out-and-out removal

Comment: +1 for the tooltip, but I'm against hiding the button

Comment: I am totally in favor of removing nonfunctional buttons.  One of the most important design principles is not violating user expectations.  Don't set them up (ooh look a handy undelete button) just to make them fall and waste their time.

Comment: As a note, [Joel wrote about such things some time ago.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/07/01.html)

Comment: @PaddedCell Hmm, interesting, not sure I disagree with that logic.  But they're *already* hiding the Edit button when there's a pending suggestion and so on, so it should be consistent!

Comment: It makes sense to hide buttons that are non-functional. I've never seen the undelete button work, because the messages I want to undelete are the ones that are deleted by mods.

Answer (score 3):

Hiding the button is not good rather than, when an user clicks on undelete button, it should show some proper message.

Comment: Why? The easiest way to say "you can't undelete this" is to not provide a method of undeletion.  Your method just wastes the user's time, having made them think "undelete" would, y'know, undelete.  Bad design.

Comment: @Matthew Then we'd start getting "why isn't there an undelete button on my answer" questions here.