# Blacklist for display names

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, display-names, blocklist, status-completed

I just noticed a(n unregistered) user on Super User who'd set his/her/its display name to the famous four-letter English word for *"fecal matter"*.

I've manually edited the offending display name to something G-rated (...I think...), but I don't really have any means, short of suspension, of preventing the user from changing it back.

Perhaps a blacklist for display names is in order?

(Diamond moderators can check the list of recent annotations for a direct link to the user.)

Comment: Was it "Beck" or "Rush"? And do they really translate outside of the US?

Comment: @random: spotted another one using the acronymized form of the name of a Van Halen album.  (also, say what you want about Beck, but you better watch what you're callin' Rush. :)

Comment: The only problem with this I can see is that apparently innocuous words in one language can be a swear word in another. It would be an ever growing list.

Comment: yeah, that does get into some thorny how-do-you-tell issues.  the only alternative i can think of is to periodically do a manual sweep... or maybe an automated-report-emailed-to-the-mod-teams.  hmm.

Comment: Maybe his name is Steven Hit?

Comment: Jeff hasn't implemented the tag black list yet and you ask for one more?

Comment: @balpha: with an email of f---@f---.f---? yeah, i'm gonna go with "probably not".

Comment: SO accepts E-Mail addresses from the `.f---` tld?

Comment: @Chris: to that I'd say that since English is the language of choice for the trilogy, that's what the list should bounce against.

Comment: @squillman: what about words in other languages that *sound* offensive to *someone* in English?

Comment: @voyager: I know where you're going, and I agree with you.  I'm just saying that **IF** any kind of blacklist were to employed that it should work against the English dictionary, as it's been made clear that the official language for the trilogy communities is English.

Comment: Maybe his name is Steven Henry Ian Thompson. Must be hard going through life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We already have a regex blacklist for global terms on the site, and there is a username category.

We wouldn't attempt to put curse words in it, though, right now it just has certain patented pharmaceutical names in the form `\bfoo\b` which are very unique and unlikely to ever conflict.

Comment: Any chance of adding that mythical tag blacklist/whitelist?

Answer (score 15):

I'm against any kind of automated blacklist.

See the *Consbreastution of USA* and *I'm going to insert my long necked Giraffe in your fluffy bunny*.

May be an auto flagging system for notification of mods, so they can check it case by case, but I'd fear that they (you) would feel compelled to use it for increasingly innocuous words.

Remember, I get offended by *people* and the word *compassion*. Would I have to change a Red avatar? A white one? If my name was *pelotudo*? *John Fuk*?

This case is probably just a kid, but on other cases it might be not so clear cut.

Comment: That sort of stuff is known as the Scunthorpe problem - which by now has really become a clbuttic sort of mistake: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem

Comment: There are a surprising number of individuals in America who have names that aren't simply words with curse words embedded within, but standalone curse words. `John Fuk` is a good example, but I've seen the same name with the proper spelling. Usually, these types of names get rejected by whoever issues the birth certificate, but sometimes they slip through.

Answer (score 1):

I'm against any kind of automated black list. I think moderators are the best approach to dealing with such circumstances, since they are better able to interpret "appropriate" names than some script would be. Some examples:

- Consider a poor, unfortunate fellow with the moniker "Richard Head". He may actually choose (for some reason) to go by "Dick Head", so shouldn't he be allowed to use that as a display name?
- In the same vein as the above, there's ["The Dick Swett Incident"](http://www.thedailyshow.com/watch/thu-february-4-2010/the-dick-swett-incident). Yes, real people actually have names like this.
- The name "Philip Oliver Holes" is likely not to trigger any automated filters, but would probably be construed as sounding somewhat inappropriate (*for those not getting it, sound it out... it would be a good porn star name*).

Comment: Let us not forget the infamous Charlotte Greene "Jack Tuat" incident on BBC Radio 4 - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlotte_Green

Comment: @Neil: not to go any further, there were some [misunderstandings not so long ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45619/insulting-resolver-one-ad/45630#45630) for a word that I didn't even know could be perceived as an insult. Even after [googling it](http://www.google.com.ar/search?q=define%3Atwit), I don't understand how you could feel aggravated by it.

Comment: There was a teacher at my old high school named Richard Hohl. Yeah, that's "Dick Hole."

Comment: @Carson: A friend of mine had a high school teacher named Dick O'Dour. He insisted it was pronounced "oh door", but kids being kids, they pronounced it "odor".

Comment: that's priceless

Answer (score 0):

I think we should have a blacklist for the obvious ones (which of course can't be shown here as examples).  It will still take moderator intervention for the edge cases, but at least the moderators won't have to deal with every situation directly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a list with 5 - 10 no-question-about-it words. I mean there are some words *nobody* can come up with a proper reason to use.

Then, as mentioned, the mod community can clean up any remaining problems.

Answer (score 0):

if SO doesn't censor BrainF*ck, then why bother about user names?

Comment: [It does](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24079/is-the-language-brainf-ck-offensive).

Comment: in that case, censor away!