# "Possible bug" tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

I wanted to reported a bug but I wasn't sure about it. So I wanted to tag it "possible bug" instead of bug. But the system won't let me : must include one of these tags -- bug feature-request discussion support.

I think it should be in the list.

Comment: Can the person would voted me down explain hiself ? How is this question unclear or not useful ?

Comment: Voting is anonymous, they just disagree with you.  It's ok.

Comment: It is always safe to just assume that Rich B was the downvoter though.

Comment: Disagree on what ? That's what I would like to understand to improve myself.

Comment: In meta, a downvote can mean I disagree with the premise of a "question"

Comment: @Silence, especially with a feature request, downvotes are often used to express a person's disagreeing with your suggestion for the site.

Comment: They think your feature request is silly perhaps..that's why I would downvote you if I felt strongly enough about it.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29717/could-we-get-rid-of-the-possible-bug-tag-on-meta -- the "possible-bug" tag is deprecated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't worry about it (too much).

Tag it as a bug.  If it isn't the community will fix your tagging.

Comment: I disagree with your "don't worry about it". I think it's always best to carefully consider what you do. However, I do agree with "Tag it as a bug" so you get (+1) from me.

Comment: I'm just being laid back, it's meta man!

Comment: lol, by "the community will fix your tagging" you mean "they will verbally (textually?) insult you until your mother calls their mother, and their mother calls your mother a dirty stupid *****, and your mother disconnects your internet to keep you from being an insensitive sod

Comment: "  <--- forgot that :-)

Comment: Probably.  However, you should probably just insult them back instead.

Comment: no, no! We need fewer insults. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15143/whats-with-all-the-rude-comments-recently

Answer (score 6):

You report it as a bug.  If it turns out not to be a bug, it will be retagged `status-bydesign`, and all is well.  Nobody will be mad at you for tagging a possible bug as a bug, that's what bug tracking is all about. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good idea, and it would also cover those cases where you're not sure whether the problem should be considered a bug or a feature-request.