# How should I tag a question that may be a Feature Request or a Bug depending on the answer to the Support part?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, meta

From time to time I post Meta questions relating to something that works in a way that I wouldn't expect it to. In those cases, the system is either working as designed but I think it should be designed differently ([feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)), or it is not working as designed ([bug](/questions/tagged/bug)). However, I often don't know if it is working as designed or not, since I don't know what was intended. In asking the question I would thus phrase it in two parts: **1.** How is this intended to work? **2A.** (for [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)) If it is intended to work in way ABC can it be changed to work in way XYZ? **2B.** (for [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)) if it is intended to work in way ABC can it be fixed to actually work in way ABC, rather than working in way XYZ as it does currently?

Should such questions be tagged as [support](/questions/tagged/support) because of the first part? Or should they be tagged with either [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) because of the second part? Or should they be tagged with both [support](/questions/tagged/support) and {[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)} to cover both parts? Or should it be asked as two different questions?

Comment: Please edit your question to avoid duplicate closure. Why is your question either not a duplicate ***or*** why shouldn't the answer to this question appear at some of these duplicates: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15244/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47640/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47646/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/972/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323129/282094 --- Answer: It's a [tag:bug] and if you are wrong it's also [tag:status-bydesign] **or** it's a [tag:feature-request] later tagged [tag:status-declined] - click those links to see answr.

Comment: @Rob Most of those don't seem relevant here. The second link just explains what each tag is used for in general, not how to deal with them in confluence. The third link is not about tags at all.  The fourth link just explains how the process works. The fifth link is about revising questions after they have been answered. Only the first link touches upon the issue raised here, and even that link only discusses something which may or not be a bug, but does not discuss how to ask a support question that will contain a follow up bug or feature-request.

Comment: Alex, The second link is a Community Wiki answer, by default it does ***or*** *should* answer this question. The third says: **Search First**. The fourth says what to do, it's your question (you decide) and it will be fixed in compliance with these rules by someone with tag edit privileges, as a moderator explains in the fifth link. Reading to the end of the comment and click on: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-bydesign/info or https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-declined/info proves that is correct. - That is [confirmed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367872/282094) below.

Answer (score 6):

I would tag it [support](/questions/tagged/support), since you need clarification on one the system's workings

> This includes understanding how features work and why they work that way,

and then either [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), depending on what you think is the most likely. You're an experienced user and probably have a hunch; if you don't, it's fine to omit it as you already have one of the required tags. Depending on the outcome, the correct one between [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) can always be changed/added later; we have many helpful regulars here who care about tags. What matters most is that **the question itself is clear** (the request for information and the request for change, and ideally your motivation for the change). This is not Stack Overflow where people are monitoring only certain tags<sup>*</sup> and ignore the rest.

<sup>*</sup><sub>: I'm not looking at you, [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) ...</sub>