# What to do with answers the author admits are wrong?

Tags: discussion, wrong-answers

I've seen a few **answers** such as:

> I tried this but it didn't work:
>
> ```
> float main(void, void) {
>   printf("holllo warld?"):
> }
> ```
>
> I am not sure why this doesn't work.

Essentially an incorrect answer is posted, with the person acknowledging that fact.

What to do with answers such as these?

Comment: [Here's a similar question I found, although it's a different focus](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15562/is-it-acceptable-to-post-deliberately-wrong-or-misleading-answers-to-homework)

Comment: In which context? Is it intentionally misleading, or does it have some educative value? (Sometimes a non-functioning example can in fact explain things.)

Comment: As always do one, or more, of the following: 1) ignore, 2) add a comment in the hope that they'll correct or delete the answer, 3) down vote, 4) flag as "not an answer". Depending on how seriously wrong it is.

Comment: @mario It is not misleading, nor is it very useful.

Comment: Then it's a clear case for using the `This answer is not useful` arrow. (Interpreting your example, I would categorize it as guess answer.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These should be flagged as `not an answer`.

Though someone added this as an answer, he actually says - this is **not** answering the question.

This is a kind of comment as far as I can tell - someone chiming in with a "me too, look what I tried!"

Comment: This is what I was thinking, although I know that the flag shouldn't be used *to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer*.

Comment: @Pubby - When I see an answer like this, it smacks of a "me too" type of comment, with an example.

Comment: +1 I think what makes this answer correct is noting that the poster actually states that "this is not answering the question". The same post, without that statement, would merely be an incorrect answer.