# This user is extremely annoying and the flag button is disabled

Tags: discussion

[I'm being haunted by someone who just wants to take down my posts.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690952/selvin) And the flag is disabled, so I though I'd report him here.
Posts:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34091356/android-studio-wont-open-theme-picker?noredirect=1#comment55935529_34091356
And I deleted the other, because he won't be quiet. But now he won't leave me alone

What can I do to make this person leave me alone? I don't mind him fixing up my questions, but he's doing it in a wrong way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's with all the rude comments recently?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15143/whats-with-all-the-rude-comments-recently)

Comment: I find your comments more concerning.

Comment: @Jon I'm not sure what you linked to answers *this* "question". We could find something else though.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. If this user was actually being abused in comments, as he insinuated in the question, then the linked question answers how to deal with it. Especially [the accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15144/162091).

Comment: @JonW But the user wasn't, so it doesn't apply.

Comment: @Jon the user can't flag and wasn't the target of rude comments. So.

Answer (score 13):

He is posting entirely constructive comments explaining problems with your answer, so that you can fix those problems and turn your question into an answerable one.  He's being extremely considerate in trying to help you get an answer to your question.

**You** are the one posting offensive and inappropriate comments by tossing around personal insults in response to someone trying to help you.

Comment: @Servy , and I consider it an offensive way to "help me. "Is that a problem? If I consider it offensive because I am sensitive, then I have the right to make him stop. And I called him a nazi in response to his rudeness. Ok, I admit it, I probably went too far, but he went further

Comment: @AbAppletic You may consider constructive feedback offensive, but no, you do *not* have the right to stop him from providing that constructive feedback.  I see nothing offensive about his comments at all, and I can't see any mod seeing them as offensive either.  Just because your'e offended by appropriate content doesn't mean it'll be removed.

Comment: I don;t consider constructive feedback offensive, I consider him following me around and bossing me offensive. He could've just got to the point. Instead:"smme again!....". Also, it looks like he removed his offensive posts.

Comment: @AbAppletic Posting constructive feedback on multiple posts, instead of just one, does not make it offensive.

Comment: Again, read carefully. Also, as you can see, in the begining, as response of what I considered offensive I said "I'm just gonna flag you, you've broken the rules; you have been offensive, and you downvoted for no reason". He could've explained why this question is wrong, or not in "it doesn't make sens ... it's like ... "I can't open door to my home, can you help me?" "

Comment: Also, he's added more proof that he's being offensive : "
 
oh ... you had added AS version, finally some information ... but still little ... now, dignose if it is a problem of AS itself or with your project ... edit: oh, I forgot, it is you... you can dignose that by creating new project and trying to open theme picker there "

Comment: i have read them carefully.  There's nothing offensive about those comments.  If you don't that his feedback was detailed enough to help you then that's not offensive.  You should tell him, politely, that you don't understand what he wants you to change, or how, rather than insulting and threatening him.

Comment: @AbAppletic That's irrelevant.  It in no way changes the quality problems with your question.  If anything it means you should be diligently accepting the constructive feedback you've been given and doing everything you can to address the described problems with your question.

Comment: I'm simply deleting this question. it has been solved by a moderator

Comment: *"It was. true. But read his edit. Now he's treating me different, as if I'm a noob"* if the shoe fits.. If i repeatedly saw the same user, and they continued posting without including any debugging attempts after repeated attempts at helping them improve their question, i would get *more and more detailed* with the comments i leave too, because obviously i hadn't been clear enough previously.