# What to do about comments that aren't really useful?

Tags: discussion, comments

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643279/) on SO about adding product version information to an SQL Server database. I knew I could just add a special table which would just contain this number but I wanted to know if there's an alternative solution.

The result is one useful answer after 5 answers telling me I should just use a table. I'm not even interested in such comments and here they are, adding noise to my question. So, should I downvote them? Flag them as noise? Or just ignore them?

Comment: Can someone explain why we can't downvote comments? I'm sure if I ask it it will be a dupe... But that would 'solve' it to some extent

Comment: Found it! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just ignore them. We need to expect a certain amount of subjective noise. If you think it's wrong or unhelpful, then downvote.

Comment: That's the easiest solution but it does make things a bit noisy.

Comment: @Alex: As Ólafur mentioned: if it was unhelpful -> downvote! It's your question, you decide what's helpful and what's not.

Comment: If the question makes it clear that you don't want a certain solution, and people still answer with that solution, the down arrow seems very handy. :D

Comment: @John are you copying the first letter of my name or do you have the accent character?

Comment: @Ólafur: Sure I have the accent character. If I have the `backtick` for inline code, I should have the acute also ;) Are you copying your name always?

Comment: No, I have the Icelandic keyboard layout, so I can do ÍÓÚÁÉ and also ÆÐÞÖ. I just didnt know that the backtick worked for you since I don't use it. I use ´ (accent) and not ` (backtick)

Comment: Jûst tóò mañy `äccénts` âröünd ´hèré´!

Comment: Accentuating the comments, right? :-)

Comment: I see you're using the Icelandic keyboard layout, you should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Comment: I can't really come up with any useful comment to this question, so please ignore this contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Be patient. You should either ignore them or downvote them if they are downright wrong.

The noise **corrects itself** given enough time for people to vote on the answers. Those with higher votes will naturally go upwards in the list and be sorted that way.

So have patience.