# What is the rationale behind allowing only upvotes on comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should downvoting be allowed on comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments)

Sometimes I come across comments that are a a bit rude for my taste (not directed at me) and I believe other users would probably find them mildly rude as well.  At the moment there is no option to downvote in order to communicate disfavor with the lack of manners on the part of the comment or its author.

If the issue is big enough there is an option to flag for moderator attention, but I don't really think the comments need to be removed or even take the time of a moderator.  Just as we encourage good comments I would like to be able to discourage comments that do not treat others with courtesy.

Is the current rationale simply that you are afraid of abuse, or to keep the system simpler?  Would you say it would be better to explain in passing that the comment was rude?

Comment: [There was a request and discussion about this here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments). **`status-declined`**

Comment: We should be able to flag comments as "Awesome"... Seriously though, it's quite satisfying when you hit that flag icon and the comment gets zapped right before your eyes, much more so than a downvote.