# Allow voting for unhelpful comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should downvoting be allowed on comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments)

Whenever we find great comments, we can give them upvotes. But **what if we find useless or meaningless comments?**

I think there should be an option for downvoting a comment below the upvote button and above the flag button.

If we had this option, users would be able to easily identify which comments are useless, the way they can identify helpful comments currently.

[image]

Comment: *> But what if we find useless or meaningless comments?* … flag them appropriately.