# Self-deleted posts by deleted users don't show "deleted by owner"

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-accounts, deleted-posts

I just stumbled upon [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37324/minecraft-version-numbers-wtf/37326#37326)<sup>10k on Gaming</sup>, which confused me a bit, at first.

[image]

So, who is this mysterious fellow with the unlinked name? A ninja? A community moderator who fell from grace somehow?

As it turns out, that was just the poster's display name before they had their account deleted.

Having a denormalized display name, but not for deletions, seems a bit weird. Shouldn't it say

- *deleted by owner*, or
- *deleted by user2974*

here?

[Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17144978/how-to-colorize-a-png-image-cross-browser-using-jquery/17198634#17198634) for those with 10k on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Flagging to reopen since the dupe was deleted for some reason, anyway one important thing it cause is privacy issue: sometimes when user choose to delete his account he does not want any trace to the old display name to remain.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd so much deletion going on, I can't keep up!

Comment: So, if it's a privacy issue, then it should say 'deleted by owner'. Both problems solved!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fixed in the 2013.7.17.854 release. [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments/168270#168270):

[image: state before update]

has the same issue and can be used for verification as soon as the build rolls out to meta sites:

Comment: So, [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: I'll retag after we push it out

Comment: Close, [but no cigar](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/168270/revisions) - still showing in the revisions list. :-/

Comment: Fixed that one too

Comment: Nice, thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: [Seems broken](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/7519/deleting-a-superuser-account?noredirect=1) (again?)