# Orphaned tag wiki edits have broken activity entries

Tags: bug, profile-page, tag-wiki, recent-activity, orphaned-wiki

If a user makes an edit to a tag wiki that subsequently becomes orphaned, the activity entries on their profile are left looking a bit broken. For example, [this user's suggested edit activity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1442874/chris-gerken?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) shows the following:

[image: Orphaned tag wiki entries]

I believe that it used to say something like "orphaned wiki" in the marked sections, which would be preferable to nothingness.

Comment: @Devs, any updates on this? Seems like this *should* be a simple quick fix, no?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII as a programmer (mostly web) myself I can tell you that sometimes the things that look most trivial are the hardest to do. Can't know the architecture behind the scenes, maybe showing this means creating whole new tables or table relations. (that said would love to hear "no" from a dev, would have started a bounty but already have three of those active @_@)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I definitely agree - the fact that this hasn't gotten any attention after a year indicates that it's not quite so simple of a fix - they probably are pointing to an invalid ID or something.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII probably, but not sure. Sometimes non fatal bugs just slip through and get buried, I revived some with bounty and it helped. ([recent example](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122832/152859))

Comment: @kroolik cool, very heroic of you to spend half your total reputation on a bounty!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, reputation comes and goes, bugs remain :P

Answer (score 14):

I have a slightly better idea. Rather than modifying the system to include some sort of useless text there that doesn't really identify anything, we should simply have the Community user **automatically delete orphaned wikis**.

This would fall in line with consistency for deleted questions and answers. Activity on deleted posts doesn't show up in that list at all. Considering that the tag has been destroyed, it makes sense for the wiki and excerpt to be "deleted" as well, like any other normal post.

Doing so would also solve the problem of users who create tag wikis will stupid crap like "do not use this tag" or just copy-paste things from Wikipedia or other sources for the quick, permanent reputation gain (I can only imagine that some users create tags just to suggest the edits with no intention of keeping the tag alive). Since the post is "deleted" any reputation gains from those edits would then be reversed as well.

How about we kill two birds with one *stone*?

Comment: Also acceptable.