# Why there is no mark for - "This comment is not good/great/inappropriate"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should downvoting be allowed on comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments)

I have seen that comment can be flagged/marked as great comment/marked as useful comment. But, I haven't seen any such that says - "this comment is not appropriate/invalidate/wrong/false comment or any such. Simply something that is in a negative sense as far as comment is concerned. Because I had seen several comments which I didn't like or I am against of such comment, so in that case I would like to mark that comment as inappropriate comment.". Can something of this kind can be added to StackOverflow in future?

Comment: <--- Hover and click the flag to see the flagging options

Comment: As I opted I want everyone to see that I dislike that comment. I know that we can flag.

Comment: That's how you say you dislike it. The Stack Exchange sites are about Questions and Answers, not about comments.

Comment: then why there is an mark for great comment/ useful comment?

Comment: I don't see what you're asking for that the hundreds of existing questions about downvoting comments don't already address. [Should downvoting be allowed on comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments) is the main one from back in the day, and [Reconsider comment downvoting to discourage rude comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140991/131713) got a lot of activity recently.

Comment: Because not all comments get rolled into the post they are on. It is a way to give them prominence (only the top 5 voted comments on a post show by default).

Comment: If you feel that a comment is factually wrong, or you otherwise disagree with it, post another comment explaining your reasoning.

Comment: If we didn't allow people to downvote comments without consequence, how else would people get their troll on without being able to pop off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments are third-class citizens. Upvotes are only there to select which ones should be visible if there are too many comments. There is no real reason to maintain downvotes.

For truly inappropriate comments there is already the possibility to flag them. Please feel free to do so.

Comment: I know we can flag, but I want that every user visiting can view that dislike/inappropriate comment as it is for great comment.

Comment: Comments are mostly unimportant anyway. The true content should be in questions and answers. Adding downvotes to comments would increase their importance. There is no need to do that.

Comment: @Bart Then why can you flag comments at all?

Comment: Flag or upvote @VectorGorgoth?

Comment: @Bart Upvote, sorry. I'm still foggy-headed, apparently.

Comment: Ha, I was wondering @VectorGorgoth. In essence, as I state in my answer, the upvotes are merely there to indicate useful comments. This allows for some collapsing when there are lots of comments, while having the top ones remain visible. But granted, liked or useful are not always the same thing. It's not an ideal system. And you don't really want all that many comments to begin with. The comment system could do with some changes, but coming up with something that actually works and remains clean is non-trivial.

Comment: @Bart Nix comments? Kidding, kidding. But seriously, adding any potential for reputation (even implied rep in the user stats) tacitly encourages comments beyond the strictly necessary, in my opinion.