# suggesting to add votes for comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should downvoting be allowed on comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments)
>   [How do comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)

Suggesting to add upvote/downvote icons to the comments.

Than author of well upvoted comment can be rewarded with points.

Comment: Comments can already be upvoted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do comment voting and flagging work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work) and see also [Should downvoting be allowed on comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments?lq=1)

Comment: Reputation for comments, no. Upvoting on comments, done.

Answer (score 3):

I don't like this idea; comments are intended to do the following:

- indicate something is wrong with the question or answer, i.e. "What have you tried so far", or "This doesn't answer the question"
- get clarifications from the original poster, i.e. "What do you mean by, 'Does not work'?"
- point users in the right direction, when the comment may not directly answer the question, but is helpful nonetheless.

Users already get rewards for having upvoted comments, specifically the Commentator and Pundit badges, why would they need reputation as well?

If there is something wrong with a comment, it can be flagged for moderator attention.

Random downvotes on questions and answers are annoying enough, I don't want to get randomly downvoted on comments now as well.