# Should we have a way to mark answers as duplicates?

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-answers

Many times I have seen answers that are exact copies of other answers to the same question, with minor changes like different variable names. This does not add any value to anything; just extra load on the servers. Could we have a way to identify them as such so they can be dealt with?

Comment: Downvote (and preferably, leave a comment explaining why). Answers like this are noise, you're right. The downvote tooltip says "it is unclear or not useful" - such answers are not useful.

Comment: I dont understand downvotes here

Comment: @Pilot [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: @Emracool accepted but comment is not mandatory. Anyone can downvote without leaving comment.At least [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/should-downvoting-be-allowed-on-comments) should be promoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality already exists, but the flags are automatic.

These automatic flags are handled by 10K users through the moderator tools:

[image]