# What to do about a wrong answer as a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

A user added a comment on a question I asked. The comment should really be an answer - but I think it's incorrect.

If the comment was a correct answer I'd just add another comment requesting the user add it as an answer so I could accept it. But if this comment were an answer I'd be downvoting it and hoping it would disapear.

I've flagged it with "custom" - mentioning that it should be an answer so it can be downvoted, but that seems (a) unlikely to be acted upon, and (b) overly involving the mods.

Should I have just pointed out that I think it was wrong, and that it really deserved to be listed as an answer?

Comment: Well, the usual way to "downvote" comments is to comment in reply to fisk it, and hope people upvote yours enough to make it clear that the original is deeply flawed.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3620/244519

Answer (score 7):

Practically speaking, the user writing the incorrect comment as an answer to be downvoted is not really going to happen (why would anyone *willingly* write something that is to be downvoted?)

If the comment is factually incorrect, write a comment stating this and the reason why (in a calm and polite manner of course). Flagging is not really to be used for factual incorrectness.