# Has my comment been downvoted?

Tags: discussion, comments, voting, down-votes, comment-voting

Other related questions such as *[Allow downvoting comments (status-declined)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/allow-downvoting-comments)* and *[Why can't I downvote comments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253178/why-cant-i-downvote-comments)*, plus the fact I actually cannot downvote a comment make me think downvoting a comment is not possible on Stack Overflow.

However I've seen today a loss of 1 reputation due to a downvote on a thread where I have posted a few comments but no question and no answer. The comments were discussed and some people didn't agree with me, hence the possible downvote, anyway I thought this feature didn't exist on Stack Overflow. See the reputation panel on my profile below:

[image: snippet of reputation log]

The post in question is this one: *[C - strip new line character from end from char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998407/strip-new-line-character-from-end-from-char/38998688#38998688)**.

So if it's not a question downvote neither an answer downvote nor a comment downvote, which supposedly doesn't exist, what is this?

Comment: Comments cannot be downvoted. You have downvoted an answer - that costs you one reputation.

Comment: @Oded Oh well I wasn't aware of that but that's correct I downvoted an answer.

Comment: You can click on the link to the post you downvoted - it is right there in the page :)

Comment: It shows the answer I downvoted but it's also the answer where the potentially unliked comments were. It seems I have not connected the correct dots ;) Thanks anyway I wasn't aware of this feature.

Comment: You do have option to flag a comment down voting is different. Comments cannot be downvoted.

Comment: @TimF: It is possible to link to particular comments, such as [your last](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283532/has-my-comment-been-downvoted#comment918967_283532).  If it were a downvote on a comment (assuming that were possible), it would go directly to the comment, not the post.  To get a link to a particular comment, click the timestamp next to the user's name.