# Why can questions and answers be up/down voted On Stack Exchange, but comments only up voted?

Tags: discussion, comments, voting, stack-exchange

In a Stack Exchange Q&A kind of system, what is the rationale for letting the user up/downvote questions and answers, but only upvote comments?

[This question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/101461/why-do-internet-forums-tend-to-prohibit-responding-to-inactive-threads) made me think about the Stack Exchange system. What is the reason behind giving users the option to up/downvote questions and answers, but only upvote comments?

I am looking for **the rationale behind** the way this kind of system works.

Comment: I am not interested specifically about this site but about the rationale behind the system. Should I reformulate the question?

Comment: See [the answer of a Community Manager](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7016/245360) for the official reason this isn't there.

Comment: I don't know why this was migrated here since on Meta UX you were already pointed to the duplicate here. Not sure why a moderator would migrate anyway...

Answer (score 0):

This is my guess.

In this kind of system only when new questions, new answers, or modifications to any of the two are made, the "post" is brought to the top in the main page.

The system can see valuable content with up-votes and invaluable with down votes (or a media of both). I think the main point is that what brings value to the site are questions and answers and comments don't enter this category. Thanks to those votes questions,tags,answers,etc. can be ordered in different ways.

**Comments are not meant to be given as much importance so they are not designed to have that functionality**, as the result of those upvotes is not used outside of the question. Removing extra functionality makes the post cleaner. But the user still has an option to give some value to a comment.