# Return to Question shouldn't forward to target site on a migrated question

Tags: feature-request, migration, revisions-list

When looking on a question that was migrated to your site, you can follow the migration notice to the source site. You will see the revision history there (the migration notice under [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287003/245360) migrates to [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/posts/101489/revisions) for example).

The problem is that there is no way to go back to the original question on the source site (UX in this case). The link correctly points to the source site, but it automatically navigates to the target site on clicking the link. I guess adding a `?noredirect=1` to the URL will do.

Can this be implemented please?

Comment: Yup, [adding ?noredirect=1](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/101489/in-stack-exchange-why-questions-and-answers-can-be-up-down-voted-but-comments-on?noredirect=1) works.

Comment: This is how it used to work. Wasn't there a reason they changed it?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, but if you do, I would love to see the feature request / change log.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Maybe [this change](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73593/323179) was responsible.

Comment: @Laurel I think that is about the front page.