# Feature Request: Comments exist, but not for users with low rep

Tags: feature-request

*Edit*
**Why my post is not a duplicate**
As commented,

> All I want is a feature to ask someone who posted a good answer to elaborate further. Because I can't do this, I don't have a solution when there's a great one that's very close to helping me. If I post to ask the same question, that will be marked as a duplicate. So what do I do?
>
> I wouldn't consider this a duplicate. Mine is a feature-request and about asking for clarification (this is a learning site) rather than being able to write a comment.
>
> ...It is much more restricted than what a comment allows...
>
> Somebody posted a snippet of their code showing a great example that would have helped me quite a bit. But the code didn't show the whole picture, and if I could have had him elaborate on what he answered, I would have fixed my issue a while ago.

*Original Post*
**The Scenario**
I was just going through a post an Stack Overflow and wanted to ask a question about somebody's answer, but was denied from commenting for not having a 50+ reputation.

My question was not something that was worth making into it's own post; it was very short and specific to what that user had answered. Obviously, it was not another answer, so I would never post it as an answer to that question. Not that this would suffice, but I looked around for a while to find somewhere to message the user, but couldn't find out how to do that either.

**My Proposal**
I suggest StackExchange and all descendants not allow users with < 50 reputation to comment normally, but allow those users (and everyone else) to classify a comment as 'Clarification' to preserve the integrity of keeping StackExchange a site for learning.

I understand the purpose for not allowing users with < 50 reputation to comment, as they may be abusing the purpose of commenting and have not proven themselves reliable for adding content. However, I don't think they should be prevented from asking for clarification, nor should they have to go out of their way to message the other user elsewhere. And if users abuse the ability to ask for clarification, we can flag or downvote to remove the comment.

Comment: There are very good reasons for not allowing users with less than 50 reputation to comment here: [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I wouldn't consider this a duplicate. Mine is a feature-request and about asking for clarification (this is a learning site) rather than being able to write a comment.

Comment: Note that here on Meta Stack Exchange, we often tend to close feature requests that go against one of the ideals or principles as duplicates of questions that explain the relevant principle. See the last section of our [FAQ on duplicate closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/377214).

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog I just want a feature to be able to better understand someone's solution, not question the accuracy or point out any mistakes; it is much more restricted than what a comment allows. For my specific situation, I understand most of what the answer was saying, but don't understand a small part about the implementation of their code and won't be able to continue with my own now. I have no way of asking the user.

Comment: Technically, moderators do have the ability to convert answers into comments in the *exceptional* case where an answer makes no attempt to answer the question, but is still valuable for some reason. **I would not recommend posting an answer with the intention of getting it converted into a comment**, as most of these answers are deleted by the community before a moderator gets around to them.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog yes I agree, that would be abusing the right to answer questions...

Comment: You might be able to clarify your question by giving a specific example of what you're asking. I think that part of the confusion is that asking for clarification is one of the main purposes of comments. If you're actually attempting to further explain an answer to make it more understandable, that's actually a reason to edit the answer (or in the case of low-rep users, suggest an edit to the answer), not to write a comment... or, if the answer is very lacking, a good time to write an answer of your own.

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ I would like a feature for users to ask the user who answered a question to elaborate further when I think the question was useful, that's essentially what I want. Would that, implemented in some other fashion still be wrong? Maybe I didn't think about other options. Maybe it could just be a button, but that wouldn't be too effective in getting the information I need

Comment: Yes, comments are intended for such purposes (asking for clarifications, etc.) but for all the experiences we've had, it's configured not to allow low-rep users to comment on *others'* posts.

Comment: @Catjita Somebody posted a snippet of their code showing a great example that would have helped me quite a bit. But the code didn't show the whole picture, and if I could have had him elaborate on what he answered, I would have fixed my issue a while ago.

Comment: OK, so how would this be implemented in a way that wasn't going to be prone to abuse? What about the request would prevent people who *aren't* leaving requests for clarification from using this feature? I do understand your frustration; the difficulty is finding a solution that alleviates that while also not leading to a bunch of noise or misuse.

Comment: @Catija As I stated in my post, "And if users abuse the ability to ask for clarification, we can flag or downvote to remove the comment." And that's quite a simple and effective solution. I'm sure someone more clever than me can think of a better way too.

Comment: It's not, though. Even users with more than 50 rep repeatedly and regularly misuse comments and they have to be flagged for removal. Some sites have hundreds if not thousands of such comments removed every month... not all, but it's a huge problem on Stack Overflow among others. Also, comments can't be downvoted and only moderators can delete comments unless the comment gets 3+ flags from users (which isn't very common).

Comment: @Catija thta's why I'm asking for a new feature... to allow users to  to downvote Clarifications for misuse and delete them

Comment: Flagging already exists. Any user with 15+ rep can flag any comment and, on Stack Overflow, the question asker and answerers can flag comments on their posts, regardless of their reputation. If you're requesting the ability to downvote comments, [that's been requested, too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/allow-downvoting-comments).

Comment: Frankly, I'm glad there is no method by which drive-by visitors who land here via Google search are able ask me to clarify old answers of mine. You'd get a lot of those "I'm having a similar issue....can you help me?" type of comments on your old answers. _"thta's why I'm asking for a new feature... to allow users to to downvote Clarifications for misuse and delete them"_ - this would do virtually nothing to mitigate the problem I see with your feature request.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this'd be a good idea.

First of all, the 50 rep requirement is set for a pretty good reason, primarily to avoid spam or garbage from new users. While it unavoidably block reasonable low rep users to post valuable comments, I believe it's a small proportion.

Secondly, any user is allowed to comment on their posts (Q and A), as well as all answers under their questions. Thirdly, given that it's not hard to earn your first rep (you just need a few decent answers to get 5 votes), 50 isn't a high threshold for commenting everywhere.

Comment: All I want is a feature to ask someone who posted a good answer to elaborate further. Because I can't do this, I don't have a solution when there's a great one that's very close to helping me. If I post to ask the same question, that will be marked as a duplicate. So what do I do?

Comment: @PeterCougan Ask a new question, include a link to the answer which you'd like more details about. Mention EXACTLY which part of the answer was lacking something. I guarantee that it will not be marked as a duplicate if you specify the section which was ambiguous, and you mention why it's ambiguous. Note that if that answer is actually missing some details, it's _very_ unlikely that only you noticed that, so there's a good chance that someone else'll comment the same thing. It's also better than a clarification comment because anybody who knows can answer, rather than just the initial author.