# Is it helpful to have a doubt indicator on comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

My current research topic is automated doubt identification on Stack Overflow comments under answer posts using machine learning models, where doubt raised in comments refers to having critiques about the answer, asking for clarification, highlighting scenarios where the answer might not work, and suggesting the answer is outdated etc. Therefore, the purpose of having a doubt indicator on comments is to allow users to quickly locate these doubts, especially for answers with a lot of comments. Hopefully, it can help users to gain a better understanding of the answer, and also make it easier for expert users to address doubts in the comment section.

I would like to hear the community's thoughts about having a doubt indicator feature on comments, does not have to be Stack Overflow in particular. How helpful do you think it is? Any thoughts about other aspects of the feature, e.g. concerns about implementation, how to design the UI so it is not too intrusive but noticeable etc? All suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Sounds like something super complex to implement properly, for almost zero gain. I'll pass. Feel free to do that as personal project of course, but I don't want SE to waste time on that.

Comment: What is "doubt identification"? What do you mean by "doubt"? What would be achieved by this that isn't achieved by downvotes?

Comment: We normally advise users to make themselves familiar with the way the network and it's various sites operate *before* suggesting any changes. I can't help but notice that on the two sites of which you are a member, you've not yet even taken the tour. Could you show us what research you've done into the impact of your suggestion?

Comment: Is this basically a request to be able to downvote comments?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow downvoting comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/allow-downvoting-comments)

Comment: Is it the normal meaning of *doubt*? Or [the Indian English meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/can-doubt-sometimes-mean-question)? There is always this ambiguity here. Perhaps use a different word? *Confidence indicator* (if it actually covers it)?

Answer (score 5):

According to the question, this "doubt indicator" will be for comments that are:

> having critiques about the answer, asking for clarification, highlighting scenarios where the answer might not work, and suggesting the answer is outdated

Those kinds of things are **exactly what comments on Stack Exchange are supposed to be used for in the first place**. We don't *need* a dedicated indicator for them because, in theory, they should make up the vast majority of comments anyway, and the vast majority of comments that *don't* meet any of those criteria can be flagged as "no longer needed" and deleted.

The only way I can see this being helpful is for identifying unhelpful comments, but if this is being done by AI then you still risk false-positives - and as the comments on (and subsequent closure of) this Meta question indicate, it may not be obvious what a "doubt" label on a comment is actually supposed to *mean*.