# Cancel upvote on comments

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I be able to cancel my up-vote on a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment)

Is there a way to cancel an upvote on a comment, and if not, why not?

Comment: I would definitely love to have this feature,

Comment: +1, I've clicked a few by accident :(

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Comments differ from questions and answers in that comments never change.

Thus, if you thought a comment was good at one time, there is far less of a chance that you should be changing your mind.

Also, since there is no reputation involved with comment upvoting, it is far less important to be able to revoke a comment upvote.

Comment: I cannot agree with this. I have several times *accidentally* voted on a comment and been unable to rectify it. I have also voted on a comment while I misunderstood what it meant. It's true these votes don't affect reputation, but **who cares**? The principle reason I vote is to help people understand what remarks are useful and right vs. those that are less helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This request has always been declined in the past because the content you voted for won't change and they are just "lightweight votes."  I'm going to take the time now to explain why they might be a little more than that.

Comment votes do three things:

- Help SO decide which comments to display initially.  This is likely okay; even if you have 2nd thoughts about a vote, that comment was obviously still significant enough for you to spend time thinking about it.
- Provide a way to blow off steam.  Voting on comments is what keeps us from seeing a lot of meaningless *"Yeah, what he said"* comments.  We don't really care what the final score is for this, but I think when users can't undo these votes it's likely to prompt them to make a comment they might otherwise not have needed to make.  Such a comment is unlikely to add any value.
- Help you spot comments from a long list that you might be more interested in.  As a discussion continues, a particular comment may not be as important anymore and you might want to be able to clear that.  This isn't the same as the first item, as I'm referring more to how the flag will stand out than what the number printed next to the comments might be.

Okay, rant over.

Comment: It makes sense, but in some case you can make a mistake and you end up upvoting something that you didn't want to upvote

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to cancel an upvote on a comment yet.