# Why can't we remove our upvotes on comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I be able to cancel my up-vote on a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment)

If I upvote a comment, I can't un-upvote it. Say if I thought a comment was a good idea and upvoted it, but then a counter comment was posted, which made me change my mind, so I upvote it as well. If the counter comment garnered more upvotes, then it could be established as correct, but it still makes little sense that we're not allowed to change our minds based on new information.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment

Comment: It’s not a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment, as it suggests to allow change the mind regardless of time limit. Referred question was only about accidental upvote that was noticed within short period of time.  However it may be a dupe of    https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134302/comment-upvote-undo-and-then-re-upvote-why-not/361775#361775

Answer (score 0):

The comment upvote doesn't indicate correctness, it indicates people agreeing with the comment.

Comment vote reversal and downvotes don't exist because they're an added complexity with no true benefit. If I remember correctly, comments on the Trilogy were added only begrudgingly, as these are not discussion forums, they are question and answer sites. Comments are, by design, the red-headed stepchildren of the Trilogy.

Since comment upvotes do not affect rep, who cares if there's a little number next to the comment that you decide you wish to reverse?

(Also, the corollary to this is that the Trilogy doesn't allow you to reverse a vote on a question or answer after a certain timeframe, unless said question or answer was edited. As comments cannot be edited, your vote would be permanent even if comment voting worked identically to question/answer voting.)

Comment: Comments were on SO from the start of public operations, and I believe were intentionally part of the design.  Votes on comments were a later addition, IIRC.

Comment: Were they? I got in at public, but don't honestly remember. Yeah, I think they were ... But voting was definitely an after-the-fact.

Comment: Many people cares does the  information on the site reflects their opinion or not.