# Comment upvote, undo, and then re-upvote: why not?

Tags: discussion, comments, up-votes, comment-voting

I recently tried to un-upvote a comment, and received a message that if I did so, I would not be able to upvote it again:

> Are you sure you want to undo your upvote on this comment? You will not be able to upvote it again.

Unlike [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130032/unclear-message-about-un-upvoting-comments), I completely understand what the message is saying. However, *why* am I not allowed to upvote it again? What's the reasoning behind this decision?

Comment: Related: some [history of the vote locks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense/18046#18046) for regular voting, the announcement of [undoing comment upvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment/129032#129032), and some [notes on the ordering of upvoted comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/17365/8).

Answer (score 9):

The only valid reason for un-upvoting a comment is if the upvote was a mistake.

As it stands, you can only un-upvote a comment within [1 minute](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment/129032#129032) of upvoting it.

Since you have to take a very concious decision to un-upvote, allowing you to upvote after un-upvoting would be rather... inconsistent.

Comment: 5 minutes? I think [it's 60 seconds](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment/129032#129032), and only if you're still on the page. I'd say it's merely to allow for flagging, as flagging is blocked once you upvoted.

Comment: @Arjan - Thanks for the link and correction.

Comment: What if the comment was edited to be something you disagree with, though?

Comment: There is more than one valid reason for un-upvoting a comment.

Comment: @nobar - for example...?

Comment: 1) Upvote, then not-sure, un-upvote, further review, upvote.
2) Upvote completely by accident, un-upvote, read comment, upvote.

Comment: @nobar - If you un-upvote a comment, you can't upvote it again. The "are you sure" message for un-upvoting a comment is clear about that.

Comment: @Oded.  Yes, I understood that.  That part I don't know is "why?" -- which is what this question is about.  I am not satisfied by the "inconsistent" rationale.  The other explanation that I have seen is "We do not want flip flopping" -- also not satisfying.

Comment: @Oded - I agree with nobar. It's not like this is natural functionality, someone took the time to craft and test this functionality. This means there was purpose, and purpose has reason. Any way to figure out who made the change, and ask? __Edit:__ Found the "perpetrator" :) - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment/129032#129032 (Mentioned in comments to original question).

Comment: @Oded: One simple reason is that you can change your mind wrt. a comment. A la "A wise man changes his mind sometimes, but a fool never." I see no harm in allowing "flip-flopping". In fact, it would probably make SE's code a few lines simpler.

Comment: I accidentally upvoted  [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20135982/perl-sql-dbi-why-doesnt-my-update-function-work-code-and-things-ive-tried#comment30011224_20135982), immediately undid it, accepted the consequences, and now regret it. Now that I've read it, I agree that it adds something useful to the post, but I can't show that now.

Comment: @Oded "allowing you to upvote after un-upvoting would be rather... inconsistent." Humans are not machines, we can think and have a good conclusion and them un-upvote. We can learn, re-think,  change the paradigm and upvote again. I think that's why StackOverflow is good... to learn, change wrong beliefs, change paradigms. We aren't making a surgery, we are just voting a comment.. we can miss and fix that.

Comment: Any non reversible action should have a confirmation dialog. I just upvoted a comment I was trying to flag (if that's the same thing as "comment adds something useful") and was not offered a confirmation or undo option. (stackexchange mobile experience i bad; crashy app, tiny buttons.)

Comment: @Oded Why are questions treated any different from comments? Votes on questions can be flipped, but only within reasonable limits. Why are the rules stricter for comments?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code - because comments are less valuable than questions and answers (which is the focus of our sites). Comments are second class citizens - you will note there are no downvotes for comments. Comments only exist to help clarify a post and once incorporated into the post are liable to be removed without warning.

Comment: You say "you have to take a very conscious decision to un-upvote" but what about when you can't see most of the comment because it's behind the modal popup demanding a decision for all of time? Certainly not the experience I have expected the last few times it happened to me and I realized something was suddenly escalated and I was screwed.

Comment: Question and answer votes get locked after 5 minutes to prevent gaming the system and tactical downvoting. Comment upvotes don't give any reputation though, so there's no point in disallowing users to undo-upvote and re-upvote.

Comment: @downvote-flagger Question and answer votes get locked after 5 minutes, but comment votes get locked after 1 minute. This makes no sense because comment votes matter much less than post votes, yet the voting rules are stricter!

Comment: I have personally upvoted, then un-upvoted a comment because I initially thought it contributed to the answer, but then came to believe its information was wrong. Following other answers and further discussion, I would now like to reupvote that comment to make sure others realize that it is indeed contains accurate, contributive information. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow sees the need to enforce some nebulous sense of lifetime commitment and overengineered consistency.

Comment: it doesn't make sense to allow un-upvote for 60 seconds whereas editing is allowed for 300 seconds... I can only imagine that there are way more comments then answers/questions and to keep the system stable this was introduced... just guessing though... but why not just block the frontend? why not just say: "hey... just wait another 5... 10... 20... 40.... 80... whatever minutes before you try again"... seems old-style, but still works...

Comment: I’ve created a feature request [Allow un-upvote and re-upvote the comments as many times as user wants](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318568/allow-un-upvote-and-re-upvote-the-comments-as-many-times-as-user-wants)

Comment: `1) Upvote, then not-sure, un-upvote, further review, upvote. 2) Upvote completely by accident, un-upvote, read comment, upvote.` - this exact thing just happened to me. Kind of a weird flex by stack to not let me re-upvote but OK!

Comment: Simple case - I initially thought that an answer was useful, and then on analysis over the next 24 hours realized it had a fallacy in it. Wanted to remove my up-vote, but cannot.

Comment: "*The only valid reason for un-upvoting a comment is if the upvote was a mistake.*" - no. Many good reasons outlined above - here's another.  I just upvoted a comment, realized it didn't quite say what I thought it said, and then decided I needed to do a bit more reading before being stuck with my upvote FOREVER.  Un-upvoted, did reading. Decided it was a good comment after all, but alas...

Answer (score 4):

On touch devices( mobiles and tablets) it’s too easy to accidentally press some button (e.g. upvote of comment), so unrestricted ability to undo any click must be implemented in any modern site.

I read some question with answers/comments on iPad and noticed, that some comment is marked as upvoted by me. I wanted to undo the upvote, and the prompt “Are you sure you want to undo your upvote on this comment? You will not be able to upvote it again.” sound very restrictive/annoying.

If comments are not first-class citizens,  such restrictions are not needed.

Just kidding:to be consistent, the site should implement for touch devices corresponding warning on the comment upvote “ Are you sure you want to upvote this comment? You will be able to undo the upvote only once”

Comment: I liked the old mobile app's method of upvoting comments: doing so was two deliberate clicks, first on the comment itself, then on the upvote button on the top of the screen. Sadly this would be difficult to do on the responsive site.