# Undo upvote if the comment is edited

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-voting

There should be an option to undo your comment upvote if a comment gets edited. It is likely that you upvote something else which gets useless or provides incorrect information after the edit.

Comment: Given that there's a 5 minute time limit to editing a comment... not usually a problem.

Comment: @Oded So you suggest that a person should keep waiting for 5 minutes to see if it gets edited or not? Seriously?

Comment: No, Oded says it is usually not a problem, which makes the development effort too high compared to the little gain.

Comment: It's just a comment. And comment upvotes have really no real meaning. So it's not a big deal at all.

Comment: @ShadowWizard An upvote says that *it adds something useful to the post*. If comment upvotes don't really have no meaning then may be there is no need for the feature of upvoting comments

Comment: Maybe, but as it stands it's simply not considered an important feature of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Well it's not really that big of an issue, but in any case: Note that you already have [60 seconds to undo a comment upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/cancelling-upvote-on-comment?rq=1) (lot's of interesting discussion there as well). The only way I could see this request possibly getting traction, @Sardar_Usama, is if you frame it as an increase in the time limit to 5 minutes, to match the edit time limit, which doesn't seem like an unreasonable thing to want. You might want to add some rationale along these lines to your request, though.

Comment: It should be allowed to undo vote unconditionally as proposed in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134302/comment-upvote-undo-and-then-re-upvote-why-not/361775#361775            “we all have the right to change our minds about any topic, for any reason, and hence vote and re-vote accordingly.”
From https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171694/dont-lock-votes-on-meta-sites/252636#252636

Answer (score 3):

I haven't had very many cases where I would have wanted this.

Either it doesn't matter too much, just like an incorrect upvote or downvote on a post, or there is another way out (flagging if the edit is really terrible). And comments are second class citizens; they don't have any influence on reputation and they can be removed at will of the moderator, so no need to worry too much about them.

All these points combined shows that there is no need for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be the most critical feature for Stack Exchange, I agree it would be nice to have.

In addition to giving the option to undo an upvote on edited comments, I'm a fan of [this idea on a similar post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8481/351462). You could let the user know a comment they have voted on has been edited by sending a notification.