# Undoing "great comment" click?

Tags: discussion, comment-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I be able to cancel my up-vote on a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment)

I clicked on the wrong comment and want to remove my "up arrow", but I don't see any way to do it.

Is there a way?  (I'm on Firefox 3.6, if that matters.)

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment

Answer (score 0):

No. Comment votes don't really mean much, anyway, so it's no great loss.