# comment up vote removes comment flag

Tags: bug, comments, flags, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow flagging a comment after upvoting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104184/allow-flagging-a-comment-after-upvoting-it)

per [Cancelling upvote on comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment) when an (possible accidental) upvote is made, then the flag icon is removed. As it is really easy to click on the wrong™ one I think that it should be changed so that the flag icon isn't removed, or that we are able to down-vote comments as well...

Comment: what are you tmarking?

Comment: what about a 60s grace period during which an comment-upvote can be retracted?

Answer (score 4):

I think being able to retract up-votes like the linked question proposes is probably the most logical. Downvoting comments has itself been downvoted into the ground every time it's proposed, and being able to upvote *and* flag a comment doesn't make much sense

Comment: I think the point was if you mis-click and up-vote instead of flagging, there's no way to fix it at the moment.

Comment: @Nick Right, but of the proposed solutions (allow flagging and upvoting, allow un-upvoting, and allow downvoting), I think allow un-upvoting is the only decent one

Comment: Not sure how I missed that first read, yes I disagree with the downvote ability, but the flag staying and changing the vote from an up-vote to a flag should work IMO.

Comment: @Nick That's true, although then I worry people would abuse flag just to cancel an upvote

Comment: I posted the feature request to, but since it was already listed I removed it. I think a 15 minute grace period would be the best way to go.

Comment: I don't know if it was around when this was answered, but what about the '**obsolete**' comment flag?  If a comment is an important addition, it'll likely get upvotes, and if it's incorporated into the answer then it would be a *perfect* candidate for an obsolete flag.

Comment: -1 Being able to upvote *and* flag a comment makes perfect sense.  If you upvote a comment and then months later it is made obsolete by an edit to the question, you should flag it as obsolete.  Oops, the software is buggy and doesn't let you.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if the behavior was consistent with everything else, clicking either one again within a certain time limit undoes the last action. However, comments aren't supposed to be that big of a deal to begin with.

With more and more people using touch enabled mobile devices, this may boil down to a usability issue in the near future .. but surely a low priority one. What remains is, comments are second class citizens to everything else. I don't think enough people (even iPad users) have found this problematic enough to complain.

Comment: More than 100 people have found this problematic enough to upvote http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104184/130885