# Users should not be able to upvote comments they have flagged

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, comment-flags, comment-voting

After a user upvotes a comment, the option to flag as noise/offensive/spam disappears, while the up arrow icon "sticks" permanently.  This has caused [minor grumbling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45368/upvote-comment-and-flag-comment-to-close) but is generally accepted as by design and not a big problem.

I just flagged a comment as noise for the first time.  Afterwards, I moused over the comment and saw that the flag icon disappeared, which is slightly different behavior, but not a problem.  However, the upvote arrow was still there.  I clicked on it just to see if it was active, and my upvote was recorded.

The upvote option should really be disabled after a comment is flagged, both for the reason that flagging is disabled after upvoting and for consistency.

Comment: This is not the case. I recently flagged a comment and I do not see the upvote arrow on mouseover. Please feel free to try it with this comment.

Comment: @The, you just got both from me.

Comment: This must be a recent bug, because I remember clearly that both icons would disappear when I flagged a comment.

Comment: While these are different questions, linking [this related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53515/comment-up-vote-removes-comment-flag) which brings up that upvoting a comment overrides a comment flag.

Comment: Note that the whole basis for this request is invalid, as it's now possible to flag a comment after upvoting it. @GraceNote What's the current rationale for keeping it as it is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug.

If you flag a comment and refresh the page, the controls to upvote that comment are removed. However, if you don't refresh the page, the controls remain, and as long as you wait the 5 seconds before you're allowed to vote again, the upvote goes through.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been fixed sometime in the intervening years.