# Allow for removing an upvote from a comment within 5 minutes

Tags: feature-request, comments, up-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I be able to cancel my up-vote on a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment)

I propose a 5 minute grace period for removing an "up voted" comment. This will allow a users accidental click to be easily removed. It is a common mistake, at least to me.

I originally removed this question because a similar question exists here [comment up vote removes comment flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53515/comment-up-vote-removes-comment-flag), but I believe its an important feature which needs a dedicated request.

Comment: 15 minutes is... pretty long. Three times the length of most grace periods we have, like editing comments/posts or changing votes on posts. If a grace period is needed, I imagine 5 would be more than sufficient

Comment: Agreed, I'm suggesting 5 minutes. Even tho I'd prefer longer... lol.

Comment: Closed! Redirecting to a "declined" feature, this isn't right. Who ever Jeff Atwood is needs to know that a good amount of people want this fix, we'd at least love a better explanation why not!