# Can you undo flag comment? (not to be confused with undo upvote comment)

Tags: support, status-completed

This https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71271/can-you-undo-flag-comment

was marked duplicate of this: [Cancelling upvote on comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/should-i-be-able-to-cancel-my-up-vote-on-a-comment)

I hope this question is more clear and that I will get an answer instead of a link to a *different question*

Comment: The missing link is that flagging comments is a form of voting.

Comment: Just not a form of up-voting. Oh well, no harm done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. However, if you accidentally flag someone, don't worry too much about it. Comments require 5 flags to be deleted—it's unlikely that 5 people will all misclick on the same comment.