# How to cancel a flagged post?

Tags: feature-request, flags, help

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cancel misclicked flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)

While reading the question that was downvoted to -3 I decided to flag it. By that time the question got edited and answers got provided already.

Can you cancel a flag? Or would this be a new feature request?

Comment: You cannot - this would be a feature request.

Comment: A "flag toggle" would be nice. I've had the same thing happen to me as the OP.

Comment: Every time I have the opportunity to ding someone's flag weight I smile.