# Why is there no way to cancel a "flag" request?

Tags: feature-request, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cancel misclicked flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)
>   [Can we have a way to undo a flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96950/can-we-have-a-way-to-undo-a-flag)

I flagged a question as not an answer because it (at first) looked like it was a "comment" on the correct answer from the original asker. After further review I could see it was actually an answer, and I wished to cancel my flag request. But there is no mechanism to do that.

Comment: Why would you need to?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancel misclicked flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags). There are [also](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96190/change-or-reverse-flag) [a](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90167/how-to-cancel-a-flagged-post) [bunch](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87660/flag-removal-is-it-possible-to-remove-your-flag-or-otherwise-indicate-it-should) [of](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96950/can-we-have-a-way-to-undo-a-flag) [others](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103383/cancel-a-moderator-flag).

Comment: 1) One has a limited number of flags to use, and
2) I don't want to waste the moderator's time.

Comment: Bad flags are rare, so they only waste *a little bit* of the mods' time.  I would simply be a little more careful about casting your flags. :)

Answer (score 1):

Every feature request is evaluated using (more or less) the following criteria:

1. How much will it cost to implement, and
2. How much benefit will accrue?

For this particular feature, the cost far outweighs the benefit.

What does a bad flag cost?  Nothing to the flagger, not really. The benefit of good flagging is your flags are given a higher priority in the moderator queue.  If a user abuses the flag system, and they get a large number of declined flags, their flags will simply not show up in the moderator queue anymore.

Allowing people to cancel their flags, on the other hand, would require writing a whole new subsystem to show you your flags, allow you to check off the one(s) you want dismissed, and write the changes to the database.  All this for a very small (it's on the order of 1 percent) number of flags that a bad flagger wouldn't bother to correct anyway.

Comment: If you simply gave us access to the database, we could do it by hand, and save you the cost of implementation.

Comment: @AdamDavis hey, that's a good idea.  We should *totally* do that.

Comment: Since the "whole new subsystem to show you your flags" now exists, perhaps the two criteria are now more evenly balanced?