# What to do if I wrongly flag an answer

Tags: support, flags, wrong-answers

Note: I didn't downvote! (yet)

Earlier today, I flagged an answer as it really wasn't an answer at the time. However, the poster later added a JSFiddle example (which didn't really answer the question either but merely repeated the OP's post) but it got a few comments going, and got the OP engaged, which resulted in some useful comments before the answerer bowed out. The OP also commented via their own comments and on other posts.

It is the habit of this particular user, s/he should have used the comments IMHO to extract the extra info needed or make their original observation in the first place, and I shouldn't have been so quick off the mark with a flag! I'm not worried about the wrong flag but what if anything should or can be done in a situation similar to this.

I know it was likely a "FGITW" type answer, where a user was hoping to edit (may still happen) but again IMO it failed this time. If it was me who'd tried it, I would delete but then I wouldn't want to delete what may be useful comments = hence the quandary and my question.

Is there anything that can be done to either retract the flag or explain why the flag in the first place (beyond the original not an answer!)?

My apologies to whoever saw my flag!

Comment: I'm kind of confused; your title is "What if I wrongly flag an answer", but you say "I'm not worried about the wrong flag". What exactly are you asking?

Comment: A wrong flag means an instant ban. Two wrong flags and we destroy your account. *Three* wrong flags and we destroy your machine remotely.

Comment: @mmyers is obviously joking. Moderators aren't as lenient as to allow more than one wrongful flag to persist on any one account.

Comment: Thinking about flagging incorrectly is a 7 day ban. It's called flagcrimethink, and it's doubleplusungood.

Comment: In fact, I have a premonition that you'll raise another wrong flag tomorrow. It's banning time.

Comment: I give in, I do not want my machine destroyed, off to take the pink  pill and hope machine is intact in the morning (mm I will know who to look for), if it isn't ... then.. (never mind the threats claire) what will I do?

Comment: Try a little self flagellation when you flag something incorrectly. Lik pavlov's dog, you'll soon cease your bad behavior.  Or drool every time you refresh your browser, I'm not really sure which.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cancel misclicked flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)

Comment: No.  And it doesn't matter.  Stop worrying about it.  Stop it.

Comment: phew glad PC is still in one piece today ;), @Will, have stopped! - didn't see the dup @Cody, thanks..  I did look for one honest

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's the worst that could happen? A moderator will see your flag, wonder what you were thinking, dismiss it as invalid. If the post was improved during the 5-minute grace window, that's most likely to happen. If there's a trace of the edit in the history, the moderator may even notice that your flag was for the earlier version and dismiss your flag as obsolete (valid but no action needed). Thus the worst that can happen is a bit of wasted time (oh, well, excrement happens) and perhaps you losing a little flag weight. The system doesn't need to be perfect, it just needs to work. And it does.

Comment: "Stuff occurs."

Comment: @Robert Bah humbug.