# Allow editing or deletion of moderator flag comment

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, flags

I just flagged an old answer of mine that I had updated, so all the comments were now obsolete.  I flagged the moderator, but miswrote "question" instead of "answer".  I wasn't allowed to flag again to correct it.

Could we please have functionality to edit our moderator flag text (triggered by clicking on the text in the User's Flag Review) so we can make those kind of corrections?  Or even delete if we think we made a mistake.  Of course, I'd expect this to only work up until the flag is processed by a moderator in some way.

EDIT:  It just happened again.  I flagged a moderator to fix something I thought they would need to do, then remembered the magic trick to fix it.  Then I tried to reflag to let them know I had taken care of it, and couldn't.  Of course, I couldn't delete it either.

**Why can't we just fix this hole in the system?**

Comment: It would be useful , I just flagged a post for low quality , but then the user modified his question which then made a lot of sense :-)

Comment: I would've just used this.  Because I tried to edit [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97839) and realized that I shouldn't have flagged to close, but instead 'not a real question'.

Comment: @MTi, I think its a valid feature request, though it could be worded much better.

Comment: I can see the feature request in that question, I guess I just got hung up on the '...role designed for the users...' which felt like this user spent no time in learning how the site works.  We have moderators, but those are really the only defined 'roles' unlike sites like wordpress where you could be an editor, author, promoter, etc.  We have mechanisms to promote questions, but not designated *people* for promotion.

Comment: @MTi, I would think `privileges` would be `roles`.

Comment: +1 I'm willing to admit my perception is inaccurate.

Comment: @MTi, you should roll-up your comments into a good answer.

Comment: This appears to be your active bounty blocking you from setting another.

Comment: @random, I guess so, but I not only looked at the bounty list, but also looked at my bounty tab, where it said I had no active ones.  Maybe just a race condition timing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of [2016](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/323179), you can fix your mistake by retracting the flag if you flagged a post. If the issue still needs moderator attention you can flag the post again with a different message. You can retract the flag from the flag dialog:

> [image: this is the flag you currently have raised, retract flag button]

If you don't remember what you wrote, you can check your flag history. Retracted flags are shown as "self-removed", but you can still see what you said:

> [image: under the post name is the flag text, your name, and a timestamp]

Note that retracted flags still count against your daily flag count — they're not free. Fortunately, most people have more than enough flags each day.

(Content blatantly copied in part from [my answer on ELU meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11876/191178).)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure this would be worth it.  In your specific scenario, the flag is attached to a post, so it shouldn't be a big deal if you say "question" instead of "answer".  The post which you actually flagged is what's important, right?

In general, even if the comment on the flag isn't exactly right, the end result is that a moderator will look at the post.  That's the ultimate goal if you're flagging.

Comment: I would appreciate this feature only because I'd like to eventually get 750 flag weight and the more specific / correct I can be, then the better my chances.

Comment: @Rebecca, I've been thinking about this for a while, and while I think the most important thing is getting a mod's eyes on the post, what's also important is giving him the help of the comment so that he can make a more informed decision quicker.  It helps me to help them if I was able to leave more accurate comments.

Comment: Implementing a 'cancel flag' might actually reduce the workload for moderators. I just copy-pasted a wrong link in a flag, the moderator will just dismiss my flag (of course). It would be good to be able to undo a flag let's say under 1 minute (same as the comments) and maybe only make the flag appear to moderators AFTER that one minute! Or imagine if you flag and in the meanwhile the OP corrects something... etc.