# Is there a way how can I edit flag?

Tags: feature-request, edits, flags

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Ability to change close reason before it gets closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/863/ability-to-change-close-reason-before-it-gets-closed)
>   [Allow editing of moderator flag comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96026/allow-editing-of-moderator-flag-comment)

I was recently in one thread that needed to be migrated to the Webmasters Stack Exchange site. I clicked Super User in the flagging box accidentally instead and I want to edit it. Is there any way to edit my flag choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The scenario doesn't solely depend on your selection, so consider that either:

- A) enough people will also flag it, then it *would* seemingly be relevant, or
- B) enough people will flag it for elsewhere, which would make it seemingly relevant there.

The bottom line is that the majority will eventually decide.

Comment: So won't anyone punish me for flagging it with bad information ?

Comment: The thing that can happen is : flag is mark as invalid, you will just lose some flag weight. No consequence on reputation or so.

Comment: For a close-vote? I'm pretty sure _they_ only tar and feather the repeat offenders providing invalid-flags.

Comment: @M'vy I'm sure that doesn't count for close-vote flagging.

Comment: Well maybe `repeated` bad flagging may be sanctioned, but not one.