# Enable the Ability to Undo Flagging of a Question

Tags: feature-request, flags, undo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have a way to undo a flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96950/can-we-have-a-way-to-undo-a-flag)

I feel we should have the ability to undo a flag if we accidentally click on the wrong flag in Stack Overflow... There should be a small delay that allows us to undo an action.

Does anyone agree?

Comment: This would also be nice if a post changed sufficiently in a short amount of time to change your mind about how you flagged it. I'd be all for this, I think it would help boost the signal to noise ratio in the queue.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96026/allow-editing-of-moderator-flag-comment