# Remove the flag you just made

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have a way to undo a flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96950/can-we-have-a-way-to-undo-a-flag)

If I flagged a question wrongly, for example, selected the wrong site it belongs or I did not read the question properly the first time or any other reason that I see fit to remove the flag I just did (ie. it is still waiting moderator review), make a way to remove it?

It could be implemented as an `x` in the stackoverflow.com/users/flag-weight/ page.

Maybe that would even reduce the number of bad flags in the queue (and prevent my flag weight being reduced by my mistake).

Comment: Think twice/thrice before flagging something. :-)  Allowing the option to cancel flags might allow everyone to start flagging very casually. This would flood moderators with even more flags.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96026/allow-editing-of-moderator-flag-comment

Comment: @Siva, true.  But I think *not adding this feature* create this -^ sort of behavior where users post 'possible duplicate of **X**' and *never* flag it.  Tim/Lance/Siva you're [above reproach](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/above+reproach)! But others appear to be doing this to avoid losing flag weight to invalid flags.

Comment: @M. Tibbits: If a user doesn't flag a post but does leave a `Possible duplicate...`, I think that should be fine. Some other user who is not so much worried about losing a number will eventually flag it.

Comment: @Siva, Certainly true.  Just frustrates me a minuscule amount because I'm trying to use the flag feature correctly, have had 3 invalid flags out of 80 which I don't *really* care about -- not going to post a question to meta, but I still think it'd be 'neat' to get to 750 and with every invalid flag I know that I'm that much further away.