# Flagging a question before it was edited

Tags: discussion

If you flag a question, and after that point the original author edits the question, what happens to the original flag?  Is it still in effect?

If the edit actually resolved the underlying reason for the flag, is there a way to undo the flag?

If the edit didn't resolve the issue, do you have to go back and re-flag the question?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96026/allow-editing-of-moderator-flag-comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This flag was (typically) 100% valid at the time it was cast.

Regardless of whether the post was later edited and fixed, **it still had problems on submission that took effort from the community to fix**.

Therefore there is no need to do anything. Correct, helpful flag as cast.

(Usually when I see a flag and think "hmm, don't see any issue here", there is an edit history and that explains why. This is another reason I tell mods to try to err on the side of dismissing mod flags as helpful, by the way. Nobody is sitting there flagging posts because they're bored and have nothing better to do, or at least, I have pretty much never seen that in my entire 13-14k flag handling history.)

<sub>Also -- attracting flags, regardless of whether they are marked helpful or dismissed have, uh ... shall we say.. a "certain effect" on new users.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

> If you flag a question, and after that point the original author edits the question, what happens to the original flag? Is it still in effect?

Yes; editing a post won't affect the flags on it

> If the edit actually resolved the underlying reason for the flag, is there a way to undo the flag?

No, flags can't be edited or undone. Lance linked to a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96026/allow-editing-or-deletion-of-moderator-flag-comment) to allow that, but it's not implemented at the moment

> If the edit didn't resolve the issue, do you have to go back and re-flag the question?

Nope, the flag will still be there

Answer (score 1):

Editing an answer doesn't revoke your flag and there is no way to undo a flag. Thus, if you flag prematurely, your flag weight will likely be decreased because the issue you raised is no longer relevant. It's a good reason to actually *talk* to the person asking the question about what they mean before flagging because some detail is unclear.

Of course, there are plenty of legitimate reasons to flag immediately, such as those darn off-topic Facebook help questions we constantly receive.

Comment: *Thus, if you flag prematurely, your flag weight will likely be decreased because the issue you raised is no longer relevant.*  No.  If you flag a post for low quality and then it gets edited, mods should pick up on that and mark the flag valid.  But really, why not just edit it yourself while you're at it instead of flagging? (:

Comment: It's easy enough for a moderator to see that the question has been edited after the flag was posted, and determine the flag was originally valid.  It doesn't make sense to decline a flag that is invalidated by an edit.

Comment: I wasn't sure that it would be easy to see that. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff possibly, and of course we encourage users to edit whenever possible... but the "very low quality" flag reason says, and I quote, "This question has severe formatting or content problems. This question is **unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.**"