# Spam Flags, Is there an ability to un-spam flag?

Tags: discussion, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cancel misclicked flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)

Just been doing my little bit on SO, and I was a bit hasten to flag an answer as spam, but then after thinking about it, noticed that it might not be spam (as there where abnormal characters in the post, it could be one of the many languages my work PC doesn't have a font for...)

Is there an ability to un-flag a post as spam (or for that matter any way to un-flag a post)? If there isn't such ability, I'd like to make that suggestion now, as it can come in handy when you're on a flag-a-thon day (like I am at the moment on SO).

Comment: Just FYI, those were Chinese characters.  It wasn't spam, but definitely could have been flagged for not being in English.

Comment: Yeah was a bit to over zealous with the spam, and then realised it could have been non-spam.  (Now if only I had the right languages installed at work...)