# Once flagged, can it be undone?

Tags: support, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cancel misclicked flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags)

After "Flagging" if a user thinks, the post or comment was not enough for flagging or the reason the user gave during flagging was not correct and should be changed, can he undo "flagging"? And if "unflagging" is possible,can he re-flag it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Flag Posts privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts):

> **Is there any way to remove flags?**
>
> There is often no need, as offensive and spam flags expire after 48
>   hours if the thresholds aren't reached.
>
> Rolling back a post to a previous state will revert to the number of
>   offensive flags from that particular revision. This allows the OP (or
>   someone else with edit rights) to rollback a post that someone else
>   made offensive in a later revision. However as a general user, once
>   you mark a post as offensive, **you cannot take it back.**