# Why isn't possible to unflag?

Tags: feature-request, flags

Today, when I was reviewing late answers & first posts, I misread "It is possible" as "Is it possible" and I flagged the answer as "not an answer".

I want to unflag it but I cannot see the option. Why isn't there an undo option for flagging and what do i do in this situation?

Comment: Leave it alone. If the flag is unsubstantiated, a moderator will invalidate it. Learn your lesson - don't flag willynilly.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags

Comment: @Oded willy-nilly is a nice one, thanks for making me learn a new phrase! :)

Comment: Because the feature request hasn't been implemented...