# No option to see / change / modify your flag with 10k tools

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools, 10k-tools

I recently got access to moderator tools privilege for 10k rep user. So I can flag posts, but I cannot see the flag raised by me for a particular post from the tools/flagged screen itself(though it goes to history). Like when you vote for closing a question or suggested-edit, your vote is recorded and if you try to vote again it will show your vote made last, this way you can change your vote if you want. And once voted the question will not show to you on review/close screen.

The flag tool shows random posts also including ones which you have flagged earlier and don't want to flag. So you can come across the same post and flag it again. I think I have double flagged posts unknowingly earlier but was not sure. And now I flagged a post erroneously, which I wish to correct.

So what do you think about it? What is the right way. Should the review style voting be implemented for flags.

Comment: A flag is a flag. You can't change or modify it even if you _could_ see it. So, why show it to you?

Comment: Related, and although not for 10k tools, still relevant IMO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87500/213634

Comment: @Oded OK, valid so don't allow to change it. But at least remove posts flagged by me from flagged posts view, until they are processed.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't see these posts.

Comment: You are right. It must have been processed already and flagged again to show up there. I thought random flags showed flagged posts again.